# Google Map Infowindow Closure?

Tags: javascript, search, google-maps, mashup, last.fm

as part of my last.fm/google maps event mashup, I have to plot markers dynamically from last.fm API onto the google map.

This is all well but when I click the marker, only the last infowindow (for one gig) is displayed. I know the reasoning for this but struggle to implement it.

Currently I'm running a PHP loop through all the dynamic gig's locations (co-ordinates) and then passing this to the javascript. This makes more sense to me - and my knowledge of PHP is much better than JS:

```
<?php 

            foreach ($gigs->events->event as $js_event) { 

            $lat = $js_event->venue->location->children("geo",true)->point->children("geo",true)->lat;
            $long = $js_event->venue->location->children("geo",true)->point->children("geo",true)->long;
            $coords = "$lat,$long"; 

            ?>      

            var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=G|00CC99|000000',
            new google.maps.Size(40, 32),
            // The origin for this image is 0,0.
            new google.maps.Point(0,0),
            // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
            new google.maps.Point(0, 32));

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

                      position: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $coords ?>),
                      map: map,
                      icon:image, 
                      title: '<?php echo str_replace('\'','',$js_event->title) ." at ". str_replace('\'','',$js_event->venue->name) ?>'

                    });

                    var contentString = '<?php echo str_replace('\'','',$js_event->title) ." at ". str_replace('\'','',$js_event->venue->name)?>'

                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: contentString
                    });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                      infowindow.open(map,marker);
                    });

                <? } ?>
```

How could I add closure without fully refactoring the loops to JS and not PHP, etc. Unless this is one of the only solutions?

Many, many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to isolate the scope of your `marker` variable is to wrap the invocation in an anonymous function:

```
var map = ...

(function() {
    var image = ...
    var marker = ...
    ...
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
})();
```

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765595/javascript-closure-variable-scope-question-i-know-it-works-but-why#1765662), the anonymous function will see anything in scope where it was declared.  So inside the function can see `map`, which was in scope when it was declared.  But outside the function, `marker` is invisible, so repeated clones of the anonymous function won't impact each other.