# How to structure javascript callback so that function scope is maintained properly

Tags: javascript, function, callback, scope

I'm using XMLHttpRequest, and I want to access a local variable in the success callback function.

Here is the code:

```
function getFileContents(filePath, callbackFn) {  
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            callbackFn(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
    xhr.open("GET", chrome.extension.getURL(filePath), true);
    xhr.send();
}
```

And I want to call it like this:

```
var test = "lol";

getFileContents("hello.js", function(data) {
    alert(test);
});
```

Here, `test` would be out of the scope of the callback function, since only the enclosing function's variables are accessible inside the callback function. What is the best way to pass `test` to the callback function so the `alert(test);` will display `test` correctly?

Edit:

Now, if I have the following code calling the function defined above:

```
for (var test in testers) {
    getFileContents("hello.js", function(data) {
        alert(test);
    });
}
```

The `alert(test);` code only prints the last value of `test` from the `for` loop. How do I make it so that it prints the value of `test` during the time at which the function `getFileContents` was called? (I would like to do this without changing `getFileContents` because it's a very general helper function and I don't want to make it specific by passing a specific variable like `test` to it.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+closures+loops

Comment: Addressing the edit, with ES6 you can use `let` instead of `var` to neatly solve the closure problem. [Demonstrated here](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/javascript-callbacks-variable-scope-problem)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

With the code you have provided `test` will still be in scope inside the callback.  `xhr` will not be, other than `xhr.responseText` being passed in as `data`.

**Updated from comment**:

Assuming your code looks something like this:

```
for (var test in testers)
  getFileContents("hello"+test+".js", function(data) {
    alert(test);
  });
}
```

As this script runs, `test` will be assigned the values of the keys in `testers` - `getFileContents` is called each time, which starts a request in the background.  As the request finishes, it calls the callback.  `test` is going to contain the **FINAL VALUE** from the loop, as that loop has already finished executing.

There is a technique you can use called a closure that will fix this sort of problem.  You can create a function that returns your callback function, creating a new scope you can hold onto your variables with:

```
for (var test in testers) {
  getFileContents("hello"+test+".js", 
    (function(test) { // lets create a function who has a single argument "test"
      // inside this function test will refer to the functions argument
      return function(data) {
        // test still refers to the closure functions argument
        alert(test);
      };
    })(test) // immediately call the closure with the current value of test
  );
}
```

This will basically create a new scope (along with our new function) that will "hold on" to the value of `test`.

Another way of writing the same sort of thing:

```
for (var test in testers) {
  (function(test) { // lets create a function who has a single argument "test"
    // inside this function test will refer to the functions argument
    // not the var test from the loop above
    getFileContents("hello"+test+".js", function(data) {
        // test still refers to the closure functions argument
        alert(test);
    });
  })(test); // immediately call the closure with the value of `test` from `testers`
}
```

Comment: What if the first block of code is in another .js file, included using the <script> tag? Would it still work?

Comment: Yes.  "Enclosing Function Scope" means that your callback function extends its scope from the function it is declared in (which has the `test` variable).  If the variables are not declared inside of any function, they will be in the "global scope".

Comment: Final question:

If `test` is changing value inside of a `for each` loop, how come the last value of `test` is the only value that is printed by the `alert(test);` code? And how do I fix it so that it prints the value of `test` that was set during the call to `getFileContents`?

Comment: Please refer to the question edits for more clarification on the above question.

Comment: @Chetan - updated with notes on using a closure to solve your loop issue.

Answer (score 7):

JavaScript uses [lexical scoping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047454/what-is-lexical-scope), which basically means that your second code example will work  just like how you intend it to work.

Consider the following example, borrowed from David Flanagan's [Definitive Guide](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596000486/preview#preview)<sup>1</sup>:

```
var x = "global";

function f() {
  var x = "local";
  function g() { alert(x); }
  g();
}

f();  // Calling this function displays "local"
```

Also keep in mind that unlike C, C++ and Java, JavaScript does not have block-level scope.

In addition, you may also be interested in checking out the following article, which I highly recommend:

- [Mozilla Developer Center: Working with Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures)

---

<sup>1</sup> David Flanagan: [JavaScript - The Definitive Guide](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596000486/preview#preview), Fourth Edition, Page 48.

Answer (score 2):

In this scenario, test will be resolved as you'd expect it, but the value of `this` might be different. Normally, to preserve the scope, you would make it a parameter to the asynchronous function like so:

```
function getFileContents(filePath, callbackFn, scope) {  
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            callbackFn.call(scope, xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
    xhr.open("GET", chrome.extension.getURL(filePath), true);
    xhr.send();
}


//then to call it:
var test = "lol";

getFileContents("hello.js", function(data) {
    alert(test);
}, this);
```

Comment: And how would I call the function `getFileContents`?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. My code looked like this:

```
for (var i=0; i<textFilesObj.length; i++)
{
    var xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    var name = "compile/" + textFilesObj[i].fileName;
    var content = textFilesObj[i].content;

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
        {
            var responseText = xmlHttp.responseText;
            Debug(responseText);
        }
    }

    xmlHttp.open("POST","save1.php",true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlHttp.send("filename="+name+"&text="+encodeURIComponent(content));
}
```

The output was often the response text of the last object (but not always). In fact it was kind of random and even the number of responses varied (for a constant input). It turns out that the function should have been written:

```
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(this.readyState==4)
        {
            var responseText = this.responseText;
            Debug(responseText);
        }
    }
```

Basically, in the first version, the "xmlHttp" object gets set to the version in the current stage of the loop. Most of the time the loop would have finished before any of the AJAX requests finished, so in this case "xmlHttp" referred to the last instance of the loop. If this final request finished before the other requests then they would all print the response from the last request whenever their ready state changed (even if their ready states were < 4).

The solution is to replace "xmlHttp" with "this" so the inner function is referring to the correct instance of the request object every time the callback is called.