# How can this recursive function for creating a range work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

From the selected answer in [this SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299500/tersest-way-to-create-an-array-of-integers-from-1-20-in-javascript/) this very ingenious function creates an Array with a range from 1 to i:

```
function range1(i){return i?range1(i-1).concat(i):[]}
```

It works perfect. Call me stupid, but I just can't get my head around *how* it works. Let's say we have `range1(5)`. Now entering the function, we have `i`, so it returns itself with parameter `i-1` (4) and concats `i` (5) to it. But here I'm stuck: how does `range1` *know* it has to do with an Array? I'd say after the first run the return value (as long as we have `i`, so `i!==0`) would be a Number. And Number has no `concat` method. Can someone explain this? What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Now entering the function, we have i,
>   so it returns itself with parameter
>   i-1 (4) and concats i (5) to it.

No, it doesn't return itself. What it does is call itself, which is the recursion, then it returns the result of that call with the last element concatenated.

So, `range1(5)` will call `range1(4)`, which will call `range1(3)`, and so on. When it reaches zero it will stop making calls and just return an empty array.

`range1(0)` returns `[]`, so `range1(1)` returns `[].concat(1)` which is `[1]`, then `range1(2)` returns `[1].concat(2)` which is `[1,2]`, and so on. When we return to `range1(5)`
it returns `[1,2,3,4].concat(5)` which is `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

Note: This function works well to create small arrays, but if you need a large array it will be a lot faster to just create the array and fill it using a regular loop.

Comment: +1 *What it does is call itself* That's what I missed and made me understand the function. Thanks!

Comment: It would be simpler to just do a loop with arr.push().

Comment: @tjameson: Yes, of course, but the question wasn't about the best way to fill an array, it was about how that specific way works.

Answer (score 11):

I've expanded this code because I find it easier to understand this way.

```
function range1(i){
  if (i != 0) {
     return range1(i - 1).concat(i);
  } else {
     return [];
}
```

The logic behind this function is that if you want the list of `3` elements (`range(3)`), you take the list of `2` elements (`range1(i - 1)`) and add `3` to the end of it `.concat(i)`. Beyond this, you just need to handle the special case that `range1(0)` is the empty array `[]` and you're done.

Imagine a call to `range1(2)`. Since `i != 0`, we get

```
range(2) = range(1).concat(2)
```

`range(1)` returns `range(0).concat(1)`, giving us

```
range(2) = range(0).concat(1).concat(2)
```

Well, what is `range(0)`? Since `i == 0`, we get the empty array (`[]`) that we need!

```
range(2) = [].concat(1).concat(2) -> [1, 2]
```

Comment: `range(2) -> [].concat(1).concat(2) -> [1, 2]`

Comment: +1 and thanks. Sorry I've selected Guffa's answer though; your answer explains it really well, but Guffa used a phrase that really made me understand what I missed in my thinking.

Answer (score 2):

The base case of the recursion is `[]`, so the tail of the recursion will return an array and the other steps will concatenate to `[]` (and previous steps).

Answer (score 2):

Let's take range1(4):

```
range1(4) => range1(3).concat(4)
range1(3) => range1(2).concat(3)
range1(2) => range1(1).concat(2)
range1(1) => range1(0).concat(1)
range1(0) => []
```

Now take the first line and replace range1(3) with its equivalent from the next line. You get this:

```
range1(4) => range1(2).concat(3).concat(4)
```

Continue replacing range1 references until there isn't any left. Final result:

```
range1(4) => [].concat(1).concat(2).concat(3).concat(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `range1` function always returns an array.

It is either an an empty array (for i == 0) or a concatenated array.

Answer (score 0):

In the base case `range1` returns an empty array which defines `concat`. As it then unwinds the numbers in the range are added to the array.

Answer (score 0):

until i become 0 nothing hapens else than caling function with rediced value, but when it called with 0 it returns [] - an empty array wich in previous call aplied a concat method... it looks like  range(0).concat(1) => [].concat(1) so [1] returned to previous call: [1].concat(2) and so on to begining