# Way to *ngFor loop defined number of times instead of repeating over array?

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there a way to *ngFor loop a defined number of times instead of always having to iterate over an array?

For example, I want a list to repeat 5 times, the loop would be something like that in C#;

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){

}
```

Desired result:

```
<ul>
   <li><span>1</span></li>
   <li><span>2</span></li>
   <li><span>3</span></li>
   <li><span>4</span></li>
   <li><span>5</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: one method is as said by @TGH and second one you can use your for loop as mentioned in question then push value of [i] in empty array and start *ngFor on that array this is also possible. you can chose either one from these two way.

Answer (score 127):

Within your component, you can define an array of number (ES6) as described below:

```
export class SampleComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.numbers = Array(5).fill(0).map((x,i)=>i);
  }
}
```

See this link for the array creation: [Tersest way to create an array of integers from 1..20 in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299500/tersest-way-to-create-an-array-of-integers-from-1-20-in-javascript).

You can then iterate over this array with `ngFor`:

```
@View({
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let number of numbers">{{number}}</li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class SampleComponent {
  (...)
}
```

Or shortly:

```
@View({
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let number of [0,1,2,3,4]">{{number}}</li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class SampleComponent {
  (...)
}
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Edit: Fixed the fill statement and template syntax.

Comment: I think the `Array(5).fill()...` is missing a 0. It should be `Array(5).fill(0)`. From  the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill

Comment: The `#number` should be `let number`

Comment: You could also use `Array.from(Array(5)).map((x, i) => i );` to achieve the same without having to use `.fill(0)`

Comment: You can make it look nicer though: `<li *ngFor="let number of [s,o,m,e,n,i,c,e,a,r,r,a,y]">{{number}}</li>`

Comment: Mitja, that you phrased it like that makes me happy. I needed a laugh. It is kind of pathetic, isn't it??

Comment: As most of cases typescript (or linter) may argue about `x` variable, asking to remove it because it's not using. To fix that you need to write: `Array(columnAmount).fill(0).map(({}, i) => i)`

Comment: @Mitja that this is still the only solution makes me really sad.

Comment: <li *ngFor="let i of [].constructor(5)"></li >

Comment: @olNoy this should be an answer, It is currently hidden behind "Show 4 more comments".

Comment: @olNoy's solution should be the right answer IMO.

Comment: To get exactly what the OP wants (each li containing a sequential number starting at 1), extend @olNoy's answer: ```<li *ngFor="let e of [].constructor(5); let i = index"><span>{{i+1}}</span></li>```

Comment: Using DanielFlippance's example I was able to achieve the span repetition using only `*ngFor="let item of [].constructor(5);"`.  I didn't need the `i` incrementor because all my spans had the same content.

Comment: @DanielFlippance why haven't you posted the answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @MeVimalkumar This question appears only allow comments at this time

Comment: creating a dummy Array for looping seems like a waste of memory.

Comment: Do not call the array constructor within the html binding, this is a much worse waste of time for angular than just defining it in the cs. If you bind anything to a method, that method will be re-called every time any data changes, because angular has no way of knowing which data change will effect that binding. If it's bound to a variable in the cs, then angular can correctly know when to react to data changes.