# How to use the "for" loop statement in an angular html template?

Tags: angular, typescript

I defined a "group" variable in the component. When the value of group is 3, I create 3 columns in the html template. The details are as follows:

```
class A{
    group = 3;
}

<th>first th</th>
<th>second th</th>
<th>third th</th>
```

How to implement this function in html template?

Comment: you can check the already existing same issue like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34405878/way-to-ngfor-loop-defined-number-of-times-instead-of-repeating-over-array?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 <th *ngFor="let item of fakeArray(3);">...</th>
```

TS:

```
 fakeArray(length: number): Array<any> {
    if (length >= 0) {
      return new Array(length);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular markup language doesn't have "for" cycle with countdown. Just make array field and iterate it one via ngFor.

```
class A{
    columns = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
}


<th *ngFor="let c of columns">{{c}} th</th>
```