# how to use counting for in angularjs 2 for(i=0; i<n;i++)

Tags: angular

I want to use a loop count in angular2. To execute a command ten times.
*ngFor work like foreach

```
<div *ngFor="item in items"> Repeatative Item content </div>
```

but i want same thing like this

```
  <div *ngFor="i=0;i<10;i++"> Repeatative Item content </div>
```

---

edit:
I've found the
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354325/angular-2-ngfor-using-numbers-instead-collections?answertab=votes#tab-top)
.
It works for me.

Comment: Why do you want it like this?
What are you trying to do? Start with that first.

Comment: i want repate a element n times like this
 <input type="file" (change)="onChange($event)"  *ngFor="i=0;i<10;i++" />

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535629/repeat-html-element-multiple-times-using-ngfor-based-on-a-number

Comment: You can build your custom structural directive that does that, if you absolutely must not use an array.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this I think:

```
<div *ngFor="item in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]"> Repeatative Item content </div>
```

Comment: thanks, but i want use something like for i=0;i++;i<n and  no arrays

Comment: Angular2 doesn't currently provide anything like that without arrays. You should be aware that the size of arrays defined in the view is limited. I don't know the limit (25 or something in that scale). You'll get an error if it exceeds that size. In this case you need to move the array to the components class.