# how to duplicate child component template inside parent on click? (angular2)

Tags: angular

I'm wondering if it would be possible on a button click to duplicate the child component template inside the parent's html syntax?

So;

```
<child-component></child-component>

<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" (click)="onDuplicate()"></span>
```

then once the user clicks the '+' glyphicon and the onDuplicate() function is called,, the parent has:

```
 <child-component></child-component>
 <child-component></child-component>

 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" (click)="onDuplicate()"></span>
```

etc etc.

I have been looking around for ways to do something like this but can't find anything so I'm not sure where to start. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ngFor` in parent template with property defined in your parent component.

// parent componet

```
public childItems: any[] = [];

public onDuplicate(){
  this.childItems.push(this.childItems.length);
}
```

// parent template

```
<child-component *ngFor="let child of childItems"></child-component>

<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" (click)="onDuplicate()"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to have children components wrapped inside an `*ngFor`, then have a counter on the class implementation. The click would then increment the counter (the source array, actually). Something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let cc of childrenCounter">
    <children-component></children-component>
</div>

<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" (click)="onDuplicate()"></span>
```

With the class having:

```
private childrenCounter: number[] = [];

private onDuplicate(): void {
    this.childrenCounter.push(0); // just add any element
}
```

The array is an ugly solution instead of a simple counter, but so far [it is necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36354325/6923555).

Answer (score 0):

Pur your  in a *ngFor directive and in your function onDuplicate() increment the loop variabile (if you have custom object just push your object into the array).