# Angular 2 repeat an icon until a value is reached

Tags: angular

I am working on my portfolio website in Angular 2 and would like to include a skill matrix. this could be any svg image or character, but for testing I use a square provided by font-awesome.

```
<tbody *ngFor="let skill of skills">
<tr>
     <td>{{skill.name}}</td>
     <td>{{skill.mastering}}</td>
     <td>{{skill.classification}}</td>
 </tr>
```

skill.mastering is a value from 0 to 10 and the idea is to use `<i class="fa fa-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>` one time for each number until skill.mastering value is reached. I have no idea how to implement this. In any other language I would write something like this in pseudo:

```
while skill.mastering > 0
print square
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this example:

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let skill of skills">
     <td>{{skill.name}}</td>
     <td>
       <i *ngFor="let key of counter(skill.mastering)" class="fa fa-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
     </td>
     <td>{{skill.classification}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Add this to your *component.ts* `counter = Array;`

Or pick another way how to achieve the same result from here [Angular 2 - NgFor using numbers instead collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354325/angular-2-ngfor-using-numbers-instead-collections)

Comment: When I run this code I get following error: 

core.umd.js:3525 EXCEPTION: Error in app/app.component.html:9:13 caused by: self.parentView.context.counter is not a function

Comment: Updated the answer, you need to also declare the counter in your component.

Answer (score 1):

if i understood your question correctly then i think you are looking for *ngIf.

```
 <tbody *ngFor="let skill of skills">
    <tr>
         <td>{{skill.name}}</td>
         <td *ngIf="skill.mastering >0">
           <i class="fa fa-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{skill.mastering}}
         </td>
         <td>{{skill.classification}}</td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
```

and i think your *ngFor should be on `<tr>` tag not `<tbody>` tag

```
<tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let skill of skills">
             <td>{{skill.name}}</td>
             <td *ngIf="skill.mastering >0">
               <i class="fa fa-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{skill.mastering}}
             </td>
             <td>{{skill.classification}}</td>
         </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Your answer is correct if you just want to show a square when the value is over 0. The idea is to show (value * squares).

so value of 8 would result in 8 squares, 6 in 6 squares.

Comment: @JanVanHaudt then you need nested  *ngFor. on second *ngFor which is a number you can use a pipe to create array from number. because *ngFor on number is not supported in angular 2.Just repeat a *ngFor in <i>  check this link for how to create array using pipe.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36535629/repeat-html-element-multiple-times-using-ngfor-based-on-a-number  i hope this will help :)