# Get index of outer *ngFor in nested *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

I am trying to get the index of the outer *ngFor in the nested *ngFor. Attaching the code below:

```
<div *ngFor="let st of s;let i = index">
        <span *ngFor="let indexnumber of i">&nbsp;</span>   //i is the index of above *ngFor
        </span>
      {{st}}
</div>
```

What I get on doing this is an error: **Cannot find a differ supporting object '1' of type 'number'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.**

How can I achieve this scenario?

Comment: You can't iterate over an index (number), only over arrays. What is `let indexnumber of i` supposed to do?

Comment: Check this out: [Angular 2 - NgFor using numbers instead collections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354325/angular-2-ngfor-using-numbers-instead-collections)

Comment: Its intented to add space before the item in the {{st}} based on index. I thought iterating over numbers was also possible with something like arr(num).fill(1) where `num` is a number and `arr` is an array defined in Component class as I saw in some of the other answers on SO. @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Thanks @pan.goth. I have already gone through such possibilities but can't figure out how to get around my scenario.

Comment: @AakashThakur something like that is possible of course. You weren't able to make it work?

Comment: No sir as you can see the error above. @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Maybe you should better use something like `[ngStyle]="{'margin-left': i + 'rem' }"` instead of doing it like 1997 HTML 3.2?

Comment: what about my answer @pan.goth linked to above?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I don't know how to use that answer in my scenario. If you can provide a plunker, I can mark your answer then.

Comment: Where do I need to use that `[ngStyle]`.@hgoebl

Comment: Replace div body with: `<span [ngStyle]="{'margin-left': i + 'rem' }">{{st}}</span> `