# Does Angular support an *ngWhile microsyntax?

Tags: angular, loops, templates, while-loop

How would I go about writing a while loop, doing the equiv of

```
while (x--) {
  <li> foo {{x}} </li>
}
```

with a "microsyntax" similar to `*ngFor` but for looping with an incrementer or decrementer rather than over an object. So if component has `x = 5`. And I want

```
<li> foo 5 </li>
<li> foo 4 </li>
<li> foo 3 </li>
<li> foo 2 </li>
<li> foo 1 </li>
```

Or the like. [Template Toolkit does this with `WHILE`](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Directives.html#section_WHILE). I'm looking for that kind of functionality. So does [jade/Pugs](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html#while).

Comment: *ngFor is for looping in template if you not explored yet

Comment: @AniruddhaDas right, I want to loop in templates with a while.

Comment: is not that possible with *ngFor?

Comment: like <li *ngFor="let foo of foos">{{foo}}<li>

Comment: @AniruddhaDas not afaik. Feel free to show me how, if it is. ngFor loops over iterators as far as I can see.

Comment: @AniruddhaDas that's assuming foo's is an iterator, what it it's the number `5`?

Comment: I dont think there is while loop in template, you need to convert your while loop in your component and then iterate that in templage. and I am sure you are not look that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 - NgFor using numbers instead collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354325/angular-2-ngfor-using-numbers-instead-collections)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count up, *ngFor has an index value available to you.  I am not aware of a way to count downwards though.

```
<li *ngFor="let foo of foos; let i = index">
 foo {{i}}
</li>
```

Output:

```
foo 0
foo 1
foo 2
foo 3
foo 4
```

Comment: Can you show what you're setting `foos` too? Is that foos=5?

Comment: It's a collection of your choice.  If you are looking to do this with just a number of times you want to increment, there is unfortunately no easy way to do this.  See [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354325/angular-2-ngfor-using-numbers-instead-collections)

Comment: Well, I was really looking for an ngWhile  or the like, not to force this to work with ngFor =(

Comment: ngFor is the only type of templating loop. So you might just be stuck using it.  Maybe if you provide more details about your specific problem someone could provide a better approach for your situation?

Comment: I'm trying a list of elements from a counter. I feel like I could [do this in the 1950s with perl](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Directives.html#section_WHILE)

Answer (score 0):

It loops through an array, put whatever you want in the array's functions:

```
<li *ngFor="let foo of foos.slice(0, 5)">
 foo {{i}}
</li>
```