# angular: repeat *ngFor for 100 or 200 times

Tags: typescript, angular2-template

This question is asked by my friend. Just want to know, Could we define *ngFor without defining array in the component for eg. minValues?

```
  <select>
              <div *ngFor="let value of minValues; let i=index">
                  <option class="min-comp form-control">{{index}}</option>
              </div>
  </select>
```

*minValues = [1,2,3,4, ....... 100] or [1,2,3 ...... 200] or [1,2,3 .... n] // here n would any constant value*

I'm thinking, we can't but not sure...

Why do we need to go to component if we just want to repeat *ngFor for n number of times, Can not we do this in a template with clear syntax like repeat ngFor from 1 to 100?

**If this question has been asked in the interview what would you say?**

Thanks!

Comment: sorry what is minValues ??

Comment: *ngFor uses any iterable objects , so it has to be an iterable

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<div *ngFor="let dummy of ' '.repeat(20).split(''), let x = index">Test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

[Angular 2 - NgFor using numbers instead collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354325/angular-2-ngfor-using-numbers-instead-collections)

shortly:

```
@Component({
  template: `
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let number of [0,1,2,3,4]">{{number}}</li>
</ul>
`
})
export class SampleComponent {
 (...)
}
```