# How to replicate normal for loop to *ngFor

Tags: angular, angular6

```
rating = 4;
for(i=0; i < rating ; i++){ 
//print statement
}
```

how to replicate the same for loop with conditions in angular 6 using *ngFor

the loop should run based on the rating value.. if it is 2 it should run for 2 times....

Comment: I would suggest you make the [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial) to learn the principles of angular.

Comment: ngFor only works on lists etc it cant be used as for loop.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354325/angular-2-ngfor-using-numbers-instead-collections

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 - NgFor using numbers instead collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354325/angular-2-ngfor-using-numbers-instead-collections)

Comment: i want to run the for loop based on the rating value....

Comment: @Sravya, just use < div *repeat="rating">< /div>. ("rating" is a variable in your .ts). If you need the "index", < div *repeat="ratting";let index>.. here you can use index..</ div>

Answer (score 1):

I think you looking for this kind of solution, 
Just create one empty array with your rating length

component

```
let items = [];
for(i=0; i < rating ; i++){ 
 items.push(i);
}
```

Use in template like

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @sravya above that code do the same thing right, if rating is '10' this loop will be run 10 times, what your use case?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I think is using a directive like @pdudits say [in the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354325/angular-2-ngfor-using-numbers-instead-collections). To improve the directive I propouse

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[repeat]'
})
export class RepeatDirective {

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) { }

  @Input() set repeat(times: number) {
    let count=this.viewContainer.length;
    for (let i=this.viewContainer.length;i>times;i--)
      this.viewContainer.remove(i-1);

    for (let i = count ; i < times ; i++) 
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef,
      {
        $implicit:i
      });

  }
}
```

You can use as

```
<div *repeat="40;let index">{{index}}</div>
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sndqui?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score -1):

You mean like `<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">{{ i }}</div>`

Comment: as @ans-bilal already pointed out, this does the trick for an array (in this case items) but does not print 4 statements as questioned