# Repeat an HTML element n amount of times using a number as a value instead of an array?

Tags: angular

I am trying to learn Angular and I have seen ngFor used to go through arrays, but I can't seem to find anything that simply repeats an html element n amount of times based on a number.

So if I have in the TS file of the component

```
public rounds: number = 5;
```

and the HTML

```
<tr *ngFor=""></tr>
```

I want the tr to repeat 5 times or however many times based on the value of rounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your component, you can define an array of number (ES6) as described below:

```
export class SampleComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.numbers = Array(5).fill(0).map((x,i)=>i);
  }
}
```

See this link for the array creation: [Tersest way to create an array of integers from 1..20 in JavaScript.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299500/tersest-way-to-create-an-array-of-integers-from-1-20-in-javascript)

You can then iterate over this array with ngFor:

```
<tr *ngFor="let number of numbers">{{number}}</tr>
```

or if you don't want to define the array in the component you could use:

```
<tr *ngFor="let number of [0,1,2,3,4]">{{number}}</tr>
```

Comment: Wow I thought there would be a much more simply way lol. I will this out thank you.