# ion-select with i to j value

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

I'd like to create a ion-select menu with ionic4 where the user can select a value from 20 to 220 but without writing manually 20, 21, 22 etc...

I've tried implementing the method of this post [Tersest way to create an array of integers from 1..20 in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299500/tersest-way-to-create-an-array-of-integers-from-1-20-in-javascript)

But I don't know how to convert this javascript code into my ionic4 app using typescript...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please show us how far you've gotten. On this site, it's the norm for question askers to put in a good effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is

- First, create an array which is going to contain the numbers

  ```
  numbers = [];
  ```
- Then in your ngOnInit function create a for loop to add the numbers

  ```
  ngOnInit() {
    for (let i = 20; i <= 220; i++) {
       this.numbers.push(i);
    }
  }
  ```
- then use the array in your HTML file like below

  ```
  <ion-select>
      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let num of numbers">{{num}}</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
  ```

If you could share your existing codebase where you want this feature to be implemented i can show you specifically where to add the codes!