# Range in Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does JavaScript have a range() equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895478/does-javascript-have-a-range-equivalent)

Is there a way to declare a range in Javascript/jQuery like we do in Python?

Something like this:

x = range(1,10)

> *x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]*

Thanks.

Comment: For fun try: `function r(start,end){  start = start || 1; return end >= start ? r(start,end-1).concat(end) : []; }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using some third party libraries like Underscore.js you can achieve the same behaviour as in Python
http://underscorejs.org/#range

Answer (score 3):

You simply can create an array, loop over the values using a `for` loop and `push`ing the values. There isn't anything built into the language.

Answer (score 3):

Put this function in your Javascript code, and you should be able to call `range()` like you do in Python (but it only works for numbers):

```
function range(start, end)
{
    var array = new Array();
    for(var i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        array.push(i);
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Just interesting, how may `[1..10]` be implemented? =)

Comment: You mean `for (var i = start; i < end; i++)`

Comment: Definitely useful, but not exactly like range in Python.. http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range :-)