# Array days or months in numbering start from day 1 or month 1

Tags: javascript, arrays, smarty

I would like to have array in numbering for days and months from starting day 1 or month 1 till todate.

For example:
Today is 05-Oct-2012

Array for days: Output (1,2,3,4,5)

Array for months: Output (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

Those array will be use in axis-x for charts.

Comment: SOF for more than 2 pages. google too but most are counted days in mths but not output till todate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Date` object together with [this useful Array.range() implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3895618/477878) to get the arrays;

```
var date = new Date("05-Oct-2012");
var days = Array.range(1, date.getDate());
console.log(days);
var months = Array.range(1, date.getMonth() + 1);  // Zero-based, so add one.
console.log(months);
```

[Full jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/m8G3D/2/).

Answer (score 1):

try this ,

PHP

```
<?php
$date= date('Y-m-d');
$dayarray=range(1,date('d',strtotime($date)));
$monthharray=range(1,date('m',strtotime($date)));
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var now= new Date();

var daysArray = [];
for (var i=1; i<=now.getDate(); i++)
daysArray.push(i);

var monthsArray = [];
for (var i=1; i<=now.getMonth()+1; i++)
monthsArray.push(i);
```

Comment: How to define it if inside template file for smarty php? Inside {php}{/php}? I put the js code but it output text 'array'...

Answer (score 0):

Use the methods of the [`Date` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```
var today = new Date();

var days = [];
for (var i=1; i<=today.getDate(); i++)
    days.push(i);

var months = [];
for (var i=1; i<=today.getMonth()+1; i++)
    months.push(i);
```