# Knockout js loop up to a value

Tags: knockout.js

I have a integer observable, `pages`, and I want to loop up to the value of pages in the html eg.

```
pages = ko.observable(3)
```

produces

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a binding that is suitable for this?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: new Array(pages())">
    <li data-bind='text: $index()+1'></li>
</ul>
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L8Uy5/

Comment: Nice answer, I was going for a much more complicated one with a `ko.computed`. Completely forgot about the $index property!

Comment: Thanks. I think that for the most cases it is better to use computed because of better control of the items. But for this situation my variant is more convenient.

Answer (score 6):

If you just need a simple `for` loop you can do something like this:

```
<select name="something"
    data-bind="foreach: new Array(10)">
    <option data-bind="text: $index()+1, value: $index()+1"></option>
</select>
```

You can specify the number of items by replacing `(10)` with any number.
This will produce a simple dropdown containing numbers from 1 to 10.

Answer (score 2):

[The answer by Artem Vyshniakov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15227504/419956) is a great quick way to get this running in the view without changing the view model. However, if you expect to expand the setup quickly, or just dislike having (what is arguably unit-testable logic) `new Array(pages())` in your view, here's an alternate solution. One additional benefit might be that you can also encapsulate the `$index + 1` bit:

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.pages = ko.observable(3);
  
  self.pageArray = ko.computed(function() {
    var list = [];
    var length = parseInt(self.pages(), 10); // the <input> makes `pages` a string!
    for (var i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
      list.push(i);
    }
    return list;
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input data-bind="textInput: pages" type="number">

<ul data-bind="foreach: pageArray">
  <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```

The `pageArray` code is mostly bulky because (a) `pages` becomes a string because of the input, which might be better solved by making `pages` into a writeable computed, and (b) because I chose to use a `for` loop / *basic* solution for creating the range (upon which [you could improve](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3895478/419956)).

Here's a suggested version that improves on both counts:

```js
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this, 
      _pages = ko.observable(3);
  
  self.pages = ko.computed({
    read: () => _pages(),
    write: newVal => _pages(parseInt(newVal, 10))
  });
  
  self.pageArray = ko.computed(() => _.range(1, _pages() + 1));
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input data-bind="textInput: pages" type="number">

<ul data-bind="foreach: pageArray">
  <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```

At any rate, `pageArray` and its contents are now fully unit testable and accessible to other bits of view model logic. (If you don't need that, e.g. you're just scaffolding a view, I'd say go with the other answer).

Answer (score -2):

it does not work on update field

> You can write something like this:
>
> Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L8Uy5/

This work better https://jsfiddle.net/L8Uy5/54/

```js
function ViewModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.pages = ko.observable(3);
    self.virtual_elements = ko.computed(function(){
        var arr = [];
        for (var i=1; i<=self.pages(); i++) {
            arr.push('some');
        }
        return arr;
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<input data-bind="value: pages"/>
<ul data-bind="foreach: virtual_elements">
    <li data-bind='text: $index()+1'></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The original version [works just fine when combined with an input](http://jsfiddle.net/8p3c80L2/) it's just less forgiving than the alternative from this answer towards `pages` becoming a *string* when using an `input`. I do like the idea of a `computed` though, but [for other reasons](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37366718/419956).