# Knockout run foreach loop on a variable instead of boject or array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

i have an object which contains a property.Like this

```
{
    "QuestionId":31,
    "ImportanceLevel":53
}
```

I bind the ImportanceLevel to a div and now i want to apply foreach loop that should run till it reaches the value of ImportanceLevel. Here is binding.

```
<div data-bind="foreach:ImportanceLevel">
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Here i want to generate span 3 times how can i do that?
If this is not the proper way as i assume so what is an alternative. this generates some ui like this

[image]

If level is three it will display 3 circles.

Comment: so for level 53 it will display 53 circles?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227373/knockout-js-loop-up-to-a-value/15227504#15227504

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another suggestion for achieving the same effect, without the foreach binding. Use a div with a width that is computed based on the importance level. To make it display tiny blue dots, you can use the background-image. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/36vLE/5/

js:

```
var VM = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.importanceLevel = ko.observable(53);
    self.importanceWidth = ko.computed(function(){
       return (self.importanceLevel() * 2) + "px" 
    });
    self.increaseLevel = function(){
        self.importanceLevel(self.importanceLevel() + 10);
    }    
}

ko.applyBindings(new VM());
```

html:

```
<button data-bind="click:increaseLevel">increase importance</button>
<div data-bind="style:{width:importanceWidth}" id="importanceBar"></div>
<br />
<div data-bind="style:{width:importanceWidth}" id="importanceBar2"></div>
```