# knockout foreach number instead of array items

Tags: knockout.js, javascript

I was wondering if there is a way in knockout to create dom items, similar to how the foreach binding works, using an observable with only an integer?

eg

```
var viewModel = function(){
    this.item = ko.observableArray(["1","2","3"]);

    }
```

this will create 3 dom elements when using foreach binding. Where I would like to see the following produce three dom items.

```
 var viewModel = function(){
        this.item = ko.observable(3);

        }
```

one addition is that the end result needs to be dynamic so if the value changes the dom items would too.

Comment: You'd need to write a custom binding handler. Show an example of what you want to do in the DOM.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227373/knockout-js-loop-up-to-a-value/15227504#15227504

Comment: Are you trying to use this observable a limit count to a list?

Answer (score 0):

Artem Vyshniakov's answer is very good but is mainly useful when you don't data bound to those created elements.

If you need to create elements based on a count but they also have data coming from an array then to create a limit count:

```
var data = [{ "Name": "John", "Age" : 20 },{ "Name": "Mike", "Age" : 30 },{ "Name": "Tom", "Age" : 40 },{ "Name": "Sam", "Age" : 50 }];

function vm(){
    var self = this;
    self.itemCount = ko.observable(3);
    self.items = ko.observableArray(data);
    self.limitedItems = ko.computed(function(){
        var ctr = 0;
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.items(), function(item){
            ctr++
            return ctr <= self.itemCount() ? item : false;
        });
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

So you can control the number of elements from the collection:

```
<input data-bind="value: itemCount, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />

<ul data-bind="foreach: limitedItems">
    <li data-bind="text: Name + ', ' + Age"></li>
</ul>
```