# Way to ng-repeat defined number of times instead of repeating over array?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Is there a way to `ng-repeat` a defined number of times instead of always having to iterate over an array?

For example, below I want the list item to show up 5 times assuming `$scope.number` equal to 5 in addition incrementing the number so each list item increments like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Desired result:

```
<ul>
   <li><span>1</span></li>
   <li><span>2</span></li>
   <li><span>3</span></li>
   <li><span>4</span></li>
   <li><span>5</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: http://ktstowell.github.io/ng-repeat-while/#/

Answer (score 594, accepted):

## Update (9/25/2018)

Newer versions of AngularJS (>= 1.3.0) allow you to do this with only a variable (no function needed):

```
<li ng-repeat="x in [].constructor(number) track by $index">
    <span>{{ $index+1 }}</span>
</li>
```

```js
$scope.number = 5;
```

This was not possible at the time the question was first asked.  Credit to @Nikhil Nambiar from his answer below for this update

---

## Original (5/29/2013)

At the moment, `ng-repeat` only accepts a collection as a parameter, but you could do this:

```
<li ng-repeat="i in getNumber(number)">
    <span>{{ $index+1 }}</span>
</li>
```

And somewhere in your controller:

```
$scope.number = 5;
$scope.getNumber = function(num) {
    return new Array(num);   
}
```

This would allow you to change `$scope.number` to any number as you please and still maintain the binding you're looking for.

**EDIT (1/6/2014)** -- Newer versions of AngularJS (>= 1.1.5) require `track by $index`:

```
<li ng-repeat="i in getNumber(number) track by $index">
    <span>{{ $index+1 }}</span>
</li>
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/cHQLH/) with a couple of lists using the same `getNumber` function.

Comment: $scope.getNumber = function(num) {
     var x=new Array();
     for(var i=0;i<num;i++){
      x.push(i+1);
     }
 return x;   
}  //use this function when the number is changes dynamically

Comment: @Manavendher Incorrect. We do not need to populate the array, we only need it to be the length of `$scope.number`. Angular's digest cycle will automatically recall this function and resize the array any time `$scope.number` changes.

Comment: @sh0ber. When I need to change the list items based on the value selected in number dropdown. I tried your function first, when it is not working, I changed it to above to update the no. of list items when different number is selected in the dropdown. Can you please check my scenario using your function.

Comment: @Manavendher  I tried with angular 1.2.x and 1.5.x with same results. Links are 
1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40202263/re-render-ngrepeat-based-on-user-typed-value-input-field
2. https://plnkr.co/edit/zcPr7oUEBBWvCSVkDvml

Comment: Just a comment - `track by $index` is required even if you're not using the value of `$index`

Answer (score 144):

you can do this:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [1, 2, 3, 4]">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: worked like a charm, tested on Chrome v. 39.0.2171.95 (64-bit), FF v. 33.1.1 and Safari v. 8.0.2

Comment: This works perfectly if you are using it in a pagination control where all you need is <li><a href="javascript:;" ng-click="SelectPage($index)">{{ i }}</a></li>

Comment: @AdityaMP, use this for ranges in javascript http://stackoverflow.com/a/31989462/3160597

Comment: Consider calling the array constructor for a dynamic-length array, as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44594836/3045563).

Comment: what if i have to repeat 120 times. Should i go with [1,2,3... 120]?

Answer (score 93):

Here is an example of how you could do this.  Note that I was inspired by a comment in the ng-repeat docs: http://jsfiddle.net/digitalzebra/wnWY6/

Note the ng-repeat directive:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="a in range(5) track by $index">{{$index + 1}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the controller:

```
function TestCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.range = function(n) {
        return new Array(n);
    };
};
```

Comment: You could also use `_.range` from Underscore or lodash to create the array:

    $scope.range = _.range(0, n);

Answer (score 84):

I think this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nu7rZ/) from this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/angular/LjwlVYMulN8) might be what you're looking for.

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Main">
   <div ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:2">
       {{item.name}}
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: read further down on the google thread link and it describes how you can use 'slice'. e.g. group1: items.slice(0,3), group2: items.slice(3,6), etc.

Comment: This answer will result in the most minimal footprint in your controllers and I believe is the preferred Angular approach as well.  IMO accepted answer should be replaced with this.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer (in my opinion) -- Most elegant, most ng-prefered.

Comment: @Cody Unfortunately, no it does not answer the question.  OP states "instead of always having to iterate over an array" and "assuming `$scope.number` equal to 5". The intent was to use an integer variable to define the item count, not hardcode it and not use a predefined array.

Comment: @Cody @sh0ber you can set the limit in your scope (`$scope.limit = 2`) and use it like `...|limitTo:limit` -- see [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drzaus/Nu7rZ/154/)

Comment: I had a requirement to limit the list to the first three items, then have a modal if the user wanted the entire list.  Using this example I got it working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 65):

A simpler approach would be (for an example of 5 times):

```
<div ng-repeat="x in [].constructor(5) track by $index">
       ...
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant. Readable, short, and no silly functions in the controller to return a new array.

Comment: I Love this way.

Comment: I just wish I understood why this syntax works but not `Array(5)` (or indeed `[...Array(5).keys()]` to get an array [0,1,2,3,4])

Answer (score 49):

I ran into the same issue.  I came across this thread, but didn't like the methods they had here.  My solution was using underscore.js, which we had already installed.  It's as simple as this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="n in _.range(1,6)"><span>{{n}}</span></li>
</ul>
```

This will do exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: This is good, but note that Underscore isn't in scope by default - you wouldn't be able to use it in your HTML view without doing something like `$scope._ = _`.

Comment: If you are using lodash or underscore, you should put it in `$rootScope` so it can be used everywhere.  Put this in your `app.run` function just after the `app.config`: 

`app.run(function ($rootScope) {
 $rootScope._ = _;
});`

Comment: This was a perfect answer for me.  It's simple and very straightforward.  Since I was repeating using a variable that had a count, I had to do ng-repeat="n in _.range(1, count+1).  Thanks for the solution.

Comment: I tried this and while _ shows up in $rootScope, the ng-repeat doesn't render anything.

Answer (score 49):

I wanted to keep my html very minimal, so defined a small filter that creates the array [0,1,2,...] as others have done:

```
angular.module('awesomeApp')
  .filter('range', function(){
    return function(n) {
      var res = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        res.push(i);
      }
      return res;
    };
  });
```

After that, on the view is possible to use like this:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="i in 5 | range">
    {{i+1}} <!-- the array will range from 0 to 4 -->
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 34):

This is really UGLY, but it works without a controller for either an integer or variable:

integer:

```
<span ng-repeat="_ in ((_ = []) && (_.length=33) && _) track by $index">{{$index}}</span>
```

variable:

```
<span ng-repeat="_ in ((_ = []) && (_.length=myVar) && _) track by $index">{{$index}}</span>
```

Comment: Best hack ever! Thanks

Comment: `_ in (_ = []).length = 33; _ track by $index` slightly smaller

Answer (score 16):

There are many ways to do this.  I was really bothered at having the logic in my controller so  I created a simple directive to solve the problem of repeating an element n-times.

**Installation:**

The directive can be installed using `bower install angular-repeat-n`

**Example:**

```
<span ng-repeat-n="4">{{$index}}</span
```

produces: `1234`

It also works using a scope variable:

```
<span ng-repeat-n="repeatNum"></span>
```

**Source:**

[Github](https://github.com/connorbode/angular-repeat-n)

Comment: This is something they should consider adding to official angular directives

Answer (score 13):

This is only a slight variation on the accepted answer, but you don't really need to create a *new* function. Only to import 'Array' in the scope:

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="ctrlParent">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="i in counter(5) track by $index">
              <span>{{$index+1}}</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);
app.controller('ctrlParent',function($scope){
    $scope.myNumber = 5;
    $scope.counter = Array;
});
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cHQLH/512/) for a live example.

Comment: up to date (2016) and much cleaner !

Answer (score 9):

### Easiest answer: 2 lines of code

**JS (in your AngularJS controller)**

```
$scope.range = new Array(MAX_REPEATS); // set MAX_REPEATS to the most repetitions you will ever need in a single ng-repeat that makes use of this strategy
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="i in range.slice(0,repeatCount) track by $index"></div>
```

...where `repeatCount` is the number of repetitions that should appear in this location.

Comment: I believe this does not let you change the number of repeats in the HTML if it is changed in the controller, unless you wrap it in a function like other answers have done.

Comment: @trysis : I'm not sure if I understand your issue, but you should replace `repeatCount` with an actual number in the HTML, and as long as that number is less-than-or-equal-to `MAX_REPEATS`, this will let you set the number of repeats in the HTML.

Comment: In my opinion, this is the most elegant way of limiting the `ngRepeat` directive. Using `Array.prototype.slice` and idiomatic JS should **always** be chosen over a library like underscore.js (browser compatibility depending).

Comment: Not a bad solution, +1, but I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44594836/3045563) is easier, and avoids cluttering the controller.

Answer (score 8):

angular gives a very sweet function called **slice**.. using this you can achieve what you are looking for.
*e.g. ng-repeat="ab in abc.slice(startIndex,endIndex)"*

this demo :http://jsfiddle.net/sahilosheal/LurcV/39/ will help you out and tell you how to use this "making life easy" function. :)

html:

```
<div class="div" ng-app >
    <div ng-controller="Main">
        <h2>sliced list(conditional NG-repeat)</h2>
        <ul ng-controller="ctrlParent">
            <li ng-repeat="ab in abc.slice(2,5)"><span>{{$index+1}} :: {{ab.name}} </span></li>
        </ul>
        <h2>unsliced list( no conditional NG-repeat)</h2>
         <ul ng-controller="ctrlParent">
            <li ng-repeat="ab in abc"><span>{{$index+1}} :: {{ab.name}} </span></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
ul
{
list-style: none;
}
.div{
    padding:25px;
}
li{
    background:#d4d4d4;
    color:#052349;
}
```

ng-JS:

```
 function ctrlParent ($scope) {
    $scope.abc = [
     { "name": "What we do", url: "/Home/AboutUs" },
     { "name": "Photo Gallery", url: "/home/gallery" },
     { "name": "What we work", url: "/Home/AboutUs" },
     { "name": "Photo play", url: "/home/gallery" },
     { "name": "Where", url: "/Home/AboutUs" },
     { "name": "playground", url: "/home/gallery" },
     { "name": "What we score", url: "/Home/AboutUs" },
     { "name": "awesome", url: "/home/gallery" },
     { "name": "oscar", url: "/Home/AboutUs" },
     { "name": "american hustle", url: "/home/gallery" }
    ];
}
function Main($scope){
    $scope.items = [{sort: 1, name: 'First'}, 
                    {sort: 2, name: 'Second'}, 
                    {sort: 3, name: 'Third'}, 
                    {sort: 4, name:'Last'}];
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Heres an answer for angular 1.2.x

Basically it is the same, with the slight modification of of the `ng-repeat`

```
<li ng-repeat="i in getNumber(myNumber) track by $index">
```

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cHQLH/153/

this is because angular 1.2 doesn't allow duplicate values in the directive. This means if you are trying to do the following, you will get an error.

```
<li ng-repeat="x in [1,1,1]"></li>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `ng-if` directive with `ng-repeat`

So, if num is the number of times you need the element repeated:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in list" ng-if="$index < num">
```

Comment: For those of you who like clean markup... Keep in mind using `ng-repeat` in this way will still output it's commented tags (`<!-- ngIf: $index < num -->` etc..). There simply won't be any `li` elements for the DOM to render. Check a "view source" on the [results pane here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZaLiTHkA/69my8wmb/) to see what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

For users using CoffeeScript, you can use a range comprehension:

**Directive**

```
link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
  scope.range = [1..+attrs.range]
```

**or Controller**

```
$scope.range = [1..+$someVariable]
$scope.range = [1..5] # Or just an integer
```

**Template**

```
<div ng-repeat="i in range">[ the rest of your code ]</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Expanding a bit on Ivan's first answer, you can use a string as the collection without a track by statement so long as the characters are unique, so if the use-case is less than 10 numbers (as it is in the question) I would simply do:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="n in '12345'"><span>{{n}}</span></li>
</ul>
```

Which is a bit jenky, sure, but simple enough to look at and not particularly confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this example.

Inside controller:

```
$scope.data = {
    'myVal': 33,
    'maxVal': 55,
    'indexCount': function(count) {
        var cnt = 10;
        if (typeof count === 'number') {
            cnt = count;
        }
        return new Array(cnt);
    }
};
```

Example for select element at the HTML code side:

```
<select ng-model="data.myVal" value="{{ data.myVal }}">
    <option ng-repeat="i in data.indexCount(data.maxVal) track by $index" value="{{ $index + 1 }}">{{ $index + 1 }}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

First, create an angular filter using LoDash:

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('times', function(){
   return function(value){
      return _.times(value || 0);
   }
});
```

The LoDash times function is capable of handling null, undefined, 0, numbers, and string representation of numbers.

Then, use it in your HTML as this:

```
<span ng-repeat="i in 5 | times">
 <!--DO STUFF-->
</span>
```

or

```
<span ng-repeat="i in myVar | times">
 <!--DO STUFF-->
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

and the 2021 version

```
*ngFor="let x of [].constructor(number)"
```

Comment: The question is for AngularJS, not Angular 2+

Answer (score 1):

Angular provides filters to modify a collection. In this case the collection would be null, i.e. [], and the filter also takes arguments, as follows:

```
<div id="demo">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="not in []|fixedNumber:number track by $index">{{$index}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
module.filter('fixedNumber', function() {
    return function(emptyarray, number) {
        return Array(number);
    }
});

module.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.number = 5;
}]);
```

This method is very similar to those proposed above and isn't necessarily superior but shows the power of filters in AngularJS.

Answer (score 1):

If n is not too high, another option could be to use split('') with a string of n characters :

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="a in 'abcdefgh'.split('')">{{$index}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i believe the split is unnecessary here. a string is already an array of characters.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem and this is what I came out with:

```
(function () {
  angular
    .module('app')
    .directive('repeatTimes', repeatTimes);

  function repeatTimes ($window, $compile) {
    return { link: link };

    function link (scope, element, attrs) {
      var times    = scope.$eval(attrs.repeatTimes),
          template = element.clone().removeAttr('repeat-times');

      $window._(times).times(function (i) {
        var _scope = angular.extend(scope.$new(), { '$index': i });
        var html = $compile(template.clone())(_scope);

        html.insertBefore(element);
      });

      element.remove();
    }
  }
})();
```

... and the html:

```
<div repeat-times="4">{{ $index }}</div>
```

[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/nicooga/pen/PqVXPj/?editors=101)

I used underscore's `times` function as we where already using it on the project, but you can easily replace that with native code.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a more dynamic solution to this - where I could increment the repeat.

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="n in newUserCount">
<input type="text" value="" name="newuser{{n}}"/>
</div>
```

Duplicator Control

```
<span class="helper" ng-click="duplicateUser()">
Create another user with the same permissions
</span>
```

JS

```
 $scope.newUserCount = Array('1');
var primaryValue = 1;
$scope.duplicateUser = function()
{
    primaryValue++;
    $scope.newUserCount.push(primaryValue)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since iterating over a string it will render an item for each char:

```
<li ng-repeat = "k in 'aaaa' track by $index">
   {{$index}} //THIS DOESN'T ANSWER OP'S QUESTION. Read below.
</li>
```

we can use this **ugly** but no-code workaround using the `number|n decimal places` native filter.

```
 <li ng-repeat="k in (0|number:mynumber -2 ) track by $index">
    {{$index}}
 </li>
```

this way we'll have `mynumber` elements with no extra code. Say `'0.000'`.
We use `mynumber - 2` to compensate `0.`
It won't work for numbers below 3, but might be useful in some cases.

Comment: did you use `track by $index`?

Comment: this is ghetto af. if you're going to be forced to have a char for each iteration you might as well do `ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4]"`

Comment: of course, but OP wants the iteration to be n times based on a variable `$scope.number`

Comment: why not 'abcd' instead of 'aaaa' and then scrap the track by?

Comment: `aaaa` was an example to explain my -not very elegant- workaround. Using hardcoded 'aaaa' or 'abcd' you get a fixed length list, but adding `mynumber-2` decimals to 0, you get a 'string' with `mynumber` chars. Say `mynumber=5`, you get `'0.000'`, then we iterate that using $index

Answer (score 0):

I am creating a reusable directive where the max number will come from another ng-repeat. So, this is an edit over the best voted answer.

Just change the code at controller to this -

```
$scope.getNumber = function(num) {
    var temp = [];
    for(var j = 0; j < num; j++){
        temp.push(j)
    }
    return temp; 
}
```

This will return a new array with specified number of iterations

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.number = 5;

<div ng-repeat="n in [] | range:$scope.number">
      <span>{{$index}}</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

simple way:

```
    public defaultCompetences: Array<number> = [1, 2, 3];
```

in the component/controller and then:

```
    <div ng-repeat="i in $ctrl.defaultCompetences track by $index">
```

This code is from my typescript project but could be rearranged to pure javascript