# Angularjs - How to 'ng-repeat' a div for 'value in ng-model'-times?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Using Angularjs, I want to create say 10 `<div>` if user inputs '10' in a text box.

```
<input type="text" id="gcols" placeholder="Number of Columns" ng-model="cols"/>
```

So whatever value user enters in this box, those many  shall be created. So my generalized question is, how to 'ng-repeat' a `<div>` for 'ng-model' times?

**UPDATE:**
Appreciating for all of your answers, I did something like following, by referring your answers. And that is working as of now, but tell me if any other logic is more efficient than this.

```
$scope.divs = new Array();

    $scope.create=function(){ //I added a button & invoked this function on its ng-click
            var a = $scope.cols;
            for(i=0;i<a;i++)
            {
                $scope.divs.push(a);
            }
            alert($scope.divs);
        };
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ng-repeat defined number of times instead of repeating over array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824853/ng-repeat-defined-number-of-times-instead-of-repeating-over-array)

Answer (score 12):

You need to create an array to iterate on it.
In your controller:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.cols = 0;
    $scope.arr = [];
    $scope.makeArray = function () {
        $scope.arr.length = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < parseInt($scope.cols) ; i++) {
            $scope.arr.push(i);
        }
    }
});
```

In your view:

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input ng-model="cols" type="text" ng-change="makeArray()" />
    <div ng-repeat="o in arr">hi</div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V9sYB/71/)

Comment: Hey I tried this. But The input box goes disabled. I can't put a value in it

Comment: Sorry. I have edited my sample. you can check the jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 6):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/JsFUW/

In your module/app/controller

```
$scope.cols =4; /* a default */
$scope.divs =[]; /* whatever these are */
```

In the template

```
<input type="text" id="gcols" placeholder="Number of Columns" ng-model="cols"/>

  <div ng-repeat="div in divs | limitTo:cols" >
    ... 
  </div>
```

---

As comment question , try this :

In the controller

```
  $scope.cols
```

In the template

```
 <input type="text" id="gcols" placeholder="Number of Columns" ng-model="cols"/>

 <h3>cols: {{cols}} </h3>
```

Do you see that value change on the page as you type ? If not your $scope.cols is not in the template scope.

Comment: H i Sujit, updated the answer with some troubleshooting, and a link to a working example.

Answer (score 1):

In your view:

```
<input ng-model="cols" ng-change="colsChanged()"/>

<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">{{$index}} {{item}}</div>
```

In your controller:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.cols = 0;
  $scope.colsChanged = function () {
     $scope.items = new Array(+$scope.cols);
  };

  //optional: if you're starting with 1 or more "cols"
  $scope.colsChanged();
});
```

Alternatively, you could roll your own directive that used transclusion to repeat itself multiple times, but that could get involved and probably isn't going to gain you much.