# Create dynamic grid in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs, I want to create grid of 12*12

I was able to get it using following options -
1. Use nested for loop and append elements to the parent div appropriately.
2. Create static grid

but above options are not involving angular framework at all. :(

What is the best way to do it in angular ? means where should I write the loop (in controller ?) and how it will be rendered ? I tried `ng-repeat` but I could not find the way to get it done (on what data should I iterate ?).

I understand that, this might be silly question. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed use ng-repeat, that's what I did. It would look like:

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in tableData track by $index" ng-model="row">
      <td ng-repeat="cell in row track by $index" "ng-model="row[$index]">
         <!-- awesome content -->
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And if you want to make a 12*12, you will need to define in your **controller** an array of arrays 12*12:

**JS**

```
$scope.tableData = [
  ["A1","B1","C1",..."M1"],
  //...
  ["A12","B12","C12",..."M12"]
]
```

Or you can have a look at **ng-grid**, it's a great work from Angular-UI team: http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/

***EDIT*:**

If you don't need to repeat over an array but only a defined number of times, you should have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824853/ng-repeat-defined-number-of-times-instead-of-repeating-over-array) ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i do not want to have any data in controller like `tableData` because there is nothing like to store for every element. and in case of dynamic dimensions, i need to re-create the array. Will try it ! thanks.

Comment: updated answer! I added a link, if you don't feel the need to use ng-grid to solve that :)

Comment: sorry for the late reply, it helped me a lot, also I achieved it by creating grid of objects and I realized that without that object array I would not have anything to deal with. so ! thanks a lot.

Comment: My pleasure ;) Could you accept the answer if it was what you were looking for? :)