# Is this the good way to organize code for showing and hiding html depending on root in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angular to make a quiz. And I have root for Questions /#/questions/1

I got 6 questions and depending on root i show and hide html for question... Currently my code looks like this

Template

```
<section ng-class="{active:isActive(1)}">
    Pitanje 1
</section>
<section ng-class="{active:isActive(2)}">
    Pitanje 2
</section>
<section ng-class="{active:isActive(3)}">
    Pitanje 3
</section>
<section ng-class="{active:isActive(4)}">
    Pitanje 4
</section>
<section ng-class="{active:isActive(5)}">
    Pitanje 5
</section>
<section ng-class="{active:isActive(6)}">
    Pitanje 6
</section>
```

Question controller

```
$scope.isActive = function(question) {
    return question === Number($routeParams.id);
}
```

Is there a way to not use hard coded index of a section? Ore something more like in jQuery index...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `ng-repeat` with `$index` to set this up?

Add in the controller something like

```
$scope.questionsNumber = new Array(6)
```

And in the template change to (Psuedo code, not tested, check ng-repeat docs for details):

```
   <section ng-repeat="i in questionsNumber track by $index" ng-class="{active:isActive($index)}">
       Pitanje {{$index}}
   </section>
```

You might want/need to use a function instead of a `questionsNumber` as explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824853/way-to-ng-repeat-defined-number-of-times-instead-of-repeating-over-array)