# angularjs: ng-repeat over half the length of an array

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using ngRepeat angularjs to fill out a grid in bootstrap.  The grid needs periodic clearfixes.

So, for example, if the grid is:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      foo bar
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      foo bar
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      foo bar
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      foo bar
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      foo bar
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      foo bar
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this accomplishable with ngRepeat?  It seems that a structure like:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div data-ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4,5]" class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      foo bar
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Couldn't get the clearfixes in there with the iterator.

Comment: I think you should move the `ng-repeat` code into the `.row` `div`

Comment: Have you checked out this post for some answers -

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824853/way-to-ng-repeat-defined-number-of-times-instead-of-repeating-over-array

Answer (score 1):

Angular has an index property called `$index` when you're inside of the `ng-repeat` directive.  You could use this to display your clearfix div when it is needed. If you want to shortcut it even more, you could use the `$even` or `$odd` (in your case, `$odd`) property to display it every two instances.

Combining the special `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` directives, you could do something like this to get at your required result:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div ng-repeat-start="i in [0,1,2,3,4,5]" class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      foo bar
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat-end ng-if="$odd" class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

More Info: [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

Here's a Plunker to show it's working: [**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/0pYbhVgpfRquEYMLQq02?p=preview)