# Using ng-repeat to fill remaining elements for "x - available elements"

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to have 4 boxes always show up. The boxes are filled by an image,but if there is no image available I want the boxes to be gray. The `images` variable holds an unknown amount of images, it could be 2 it could be 30.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="picture" ng-repeat="image in images | limitTo: 4"></div>
    // PSEUDO CODE BELOW
    <div class="empty" ng-repeat="i in 4 - images.length"></div>
    // PSEUDO CODE ABOVE
</div>
```

***"4 - images.length" is pseudo code***, This is what I want to achieve, thinking if I only have 3 images available the result will be 1 gray box. But this syntax obviously does not work since ng-repeat require a collection.

Which made me try to provide it said collection through a function:

```
$scope.getNumber = function(num) {
    return new Array(num); 
}
```

and use in the following way:

```
<div class="empty" ng-repeat="n in getNumber(4 - cookbook.images.length)"></div>
```

But with no success.

Comment: The line <div class="empty" ng-repeat="i in "4 - images.length"></div> has a Typo : You have a "  that shouldn't be there after the ng-repeat :)
Is it working when removing it ?

Comment: Sadly, not, that typo was only made here on SO.

Comment: Can you use repeats for integers? I thought it was only for objects and it will repeat over the array until it reaches the end...

Comment: You cannot - hence why I tried using the function to return an array of required size. The "i in 4" is only ment as pseudo code to explain  my problem.

Comment: ng-repeat="i in 4 - (images.length % 4)" would be better to avoid minus 0 results.

Comment: But would cause problems if I had 6 images returned? That way I would get 2 additional boxes incorrectly?

Comment: Ho, yes, I thought you needed block of 4 boxes.
Then ng-if="images.length < 4" ? :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Possible repeat question

### By using this updated syntax you can iterate with a specific index defined

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
<div ng-controller="ctrlParent">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="i in getNumber(4) track by $index"><span>{{$index+1}}</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Controllers

```
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);
app.controller('ctrlParent',function($scope){
$scope.getNumber = function(num) {
    return new Array(num);   
    }
});
```

[Way to ng-repeat defined number of times instead of repeating over array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824853/way-to-ng-repeat-defined-number-of-times-instead-of-repeating-over-array)

Comment: This ended up being my ultimate solutions. I added a simple check to the function to return an empty array if value got below 0.

Answer (score 3):

```
 <div class="picture" ng-repeat="image in images | limitTo: 4">hi</div>
 <div class="empty" ng-repeat="n in [] | range:images.length:4">hey</div>
```

I've created a custom filter for it:

```
app.filter('range', function() {
  return function(input, min, max) {
    min = parseInt(min); 
    max = parseInt(max);
    for (var i=min; i<max; i++) {
      input.push(i);
    }
    return input;
  };
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yocetuyuli/1/edit?html,js,output)**

Comment: How is this better than one line of code that I have reference in my solution below. He would only have to make a function in the controller that returns the number as an array. one function, one line. This is unnecessarily complicated when there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: If we're thinking only about this scenario yes. But once you create a filter like this. You can reuse it anywhere in yur application. I believe in code reuse and avoid duplicating code :)

Comment: Maybe a directive might be better suited then if it gets to that point, right?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably handle this in whatever populates $scope.images.  For example, something like:

```
$http.get('api/some/images?skip=10&take=4')
 .success(function(response){
    $scope.images = response;
    for(var i = $scope.images.length; i<4; i++){
       $scope.images.push('empty');
    }
 });
```

Then my template would just handle that:

```
<div class="container>
   <div ng-repeat="image in images" ng-class="{empty:image=='empty',picture:image!='empty'}"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

wouldnt be easier to make operation modulo in controller?

```
function equal_number_of_images(){
for(var i = 0, add = 4 - $scope.some_files%4; i < add; i++ ){
     $scope.some_files.push('');
}}
```