# AngularJS star-rating to display image equal to value in key value pair?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-lists, angularjs-ng-repeat, rating

I'm writing an angular app and currently have an li using ng-repeat to display a word (which is working great). I'd like to add a star image next to the word as many times as an associated number in a key value pair, e.g. Angular: 3, would show "Angular" with 3 star imgs. Best way to do this? Here is my code:
View:

```
    <ul class="oneSkills">
            <li ng-repeat="skill in oneSkills">{{skill}}</li>
    </ul>
```

Controller:

```
    aP.controller('skillsCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
       $scope.oneSkills = ["HTML", "CSS", "Sass", "Javascript", "Jquery", "AngularJS"];
       $scope.twoSkills = ["Grunt", "Node", "Ruby on Rails","Adobe Photoshop", "Adobe Illustrator"]; }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this method to make it ng-repeat on a star image.

[Way to ng-repeat defined number of times instead of repeating over array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824853/way-to-ng-repeat-defined-number-of-times-instead-of-repeating-over-array)