# Create div with AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, metro-ui-css

I know it is very simple but I wanna ask how to create div in ng-Repeat including an object proprty defines count of object. 
For example i have an object like

```
    function rowModel() {
       this.id = 0;
       this.columnCount = 1;
    }
```

And I filled an array like below

```
    $scope.Rows = [];
        $scope.AddRow = function() {
        var newRow = new rowModel();
        newRow.id = 1;
        newRow.columnCount = 3;
        $scope.Rows.push(newRow);
    }
```

I just wanna create an html template including 3 divs in each row. 
This is my html and I wanna duplicate .cell div 3 times which is defined in object model

```
<button class="button" ng-click="AddRow()">Satır Ekle</button>
<div class="row cells{{row.columnCount}} bg-cyan" ng-repeat="row in Rows">
    <div class="cell" ng-repeat="column in row.columnCount">{{row.id}}</div>
</div>
```

Anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code in your controller

```
$scope.getNumber = function(num) {
    return new Array(num);   
}
```

And use the following in your view

```
<button class="button" ng-click="AddRow()">Satır Ekle</button>
<div class="row cells{{row.columnCount}} bg-cyan" ng-repeat="row in Rows">
    <div class="cell" ng-repeat="column in getNumber(row.columnCount)  track by $index">{{row.id}}</div>
</div>
```

Also if you do not want touch controller you can do this
ng-repeat="_ in ((_ = []) && (_.length=row.columnCount) && _) track by $index"

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824853/way-to-ng-repeat-defined-number-of-times-instead-of-repeating-over-array) is the post where I found it.

Answer (score 0):

i would create a filter for this

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .filter('range', function(){
    return function(n) {
      var res = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        res.push(i);
      }
      return res;
    };
  });
```

After that, on the view is possible to use like this:

```
<div class="cell" ng-repeat="column in row.columnCount | range">{{row.id}}</div>
```