# Angularjs Directive that repeats over an array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have setup the following directive:

```
app.directive('starRating', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            rating: '=rating'
        },
        template:
            '<ul class=\'list-unstyled\'>' +
                '<li><span class=\'glypicon glyphicon-star\'></span></li>' +
            '</ul>'
    };
});
```

I then have the following HTML:

`<star-rating rating="rating"></star-rating>`

`rating` is an array as such: `[1,3,2,4,5]` and this implies that the first rating is 1 star, 2nd rating is 3 stars, ect.

The goal of the directive is to repeat the amount of `.glyphicon-star` icons of the rating.

Comment: I referred to this answer to accomplish the requirement without the use of a directive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824853/way-to-ng-repeat-defined-number-of-times-instead-of-repeating-over-array

Comment: A directive may be useful here since it may be repeated a lot through his app

Comment: use [ngBehavior](https://github.com/maherAshori/ngBehavior#ngrating), this directive can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to concatenate the 'li' elements inside the 'ul' in the template. This is cheaper than using an ng-repeat. You probably dont need to use a list (ul's and li's) at all.

Also your scope can simply be:

```
 scope: {
        rating: '='
    },
```