# How to print 1 to 10 using ng-options without any js code?

Tags: angularjs

I don't want to use any Javascript code or $scope variable.
Just want to print 1,2,3,4,5 values in Drop Down using ng-options.

This is what I have tried:

```
<select ng-name="priority" ng-options="priority for priority in Range(1, 5)"></select>
```

Comment: Did you try anything at all? If so, please show your code.

Comment: Then why to tag the question with JS, if you don't want to use it?

Comment: There's plenty of good answers in the following thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824853/way-to-ng-repeat-defined-number-of-times-instead-of-repeating-over-array

Comment: <select ng-name="priority" ng-options="priority for priority in Range(1, 5)"></select>

Comment: I can't see ng-options used here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824853/way-to-ng-repeat-defined-number-of-times-instead-of-repeating-over-array

Comment: @user3510767 Please edit your question to add information (I've added your code from the comment above), and also explain what went wrong and how. I don't dare to add "But it's not working" to your question ; ). Something like "But the select element is not populated" would do?

Comment: There is simple drop down box. In which, I want to print numbers from 1 to 5. I want to use ng-options directive and don't want to use any js code. How could I do that.?

Comment: Yes, that's already clear. What your current code does instead of expected results? Add the answer to your post, don't post is as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Working solution, within your requirements:

```
<select ng-model="priority" ng-options="priority for priority in [1,2,3,4,5]"></select>
```

Just in case, here's the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/el5m0SnfQCuIELQ55vqt?p=preview) to experiment with. If you have a quick look at the [angular source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngOptions.js#L749), you will see that `ng-options` requires `select` element as well as `ng-model`. Not sure what is the `Range` implementation mentioned in your example, but here is a [very creative thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/create-a-javascript-array-containing-1-n) on this topic. Though, if your array is always the same and you really don't want to use `scope` (but why?), you're better off with the solution above.