# how to use ng-repeat in columns in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to make one demo in which i have one **checkbox** list .I am able to display the list using ng-repeat .

But I am tying to generate dynamic columns ..I know bootstrap grid system (12 column logic)..I also know **xs** generate automatically width .

What I need if user click on one check box(only one checkbox is checked) .it display only one columns (100%) width .Which user checked two column it display two columns of equal width (50%).if user check three column it show three column of equal width ..As as if user checked four checkbox it show four column of equal width

here is my code
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VemNpo?editors=101

```
 this.checkBoxClick=function(obj){
    this.count=0;
    obj.checked=true;
    console.log(this.data);
    var len=this.data.length;
   for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
     var checked =this.data[i].checked;
     if(checked){
       this.count++;
     }
   }
    alert(this.count)
  }
```

here is i am trying to display

```
<!-- equal width columns -->

<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class='row'>
  <div class='col-xs-2'>
    hi
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

any update..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so here you have 2 steps for the solution, for the css/class part which manipulates the width of the column it can be done as the following:

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-{{12/count}}'>
      hi
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

where count is the one you have the number of checked boxes in. The second part is to repeat the column according to the count, which by using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824853/way-to-ng-repeat-defined-number-of-times-instead-of-repeating-over-array) you can achieve by the following code:

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div ng-repeat="i in vm.selectedList" class='col-xs-{{12/vm.selectedList.length}}'>
      hi
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyGPmq

Comment: @RayonDabre please post your answer ..and approch