# How to do for loop in AngularJS without ng-repeat

Tags: php, html, angularjs

I need a `for` loop inside AngularJS. I have `$scope.num=4;`

I need something like this:

```
for(i=0 ; i<=num; i++){
    <td>&nbsp; </td>
}
```

Please help me to do this in AngularJS.

I have tried `ng-repeat`, but I can't get what I need.

Comment: is what you need is to print <td>&nbsp; </td> for num times?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824853/way-to-ng-repeat-defined-number-of-times-instead-of-repeating-over-array