# if $scope.val =3 then run the loop for 3 times using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

> I have a scenario in application, where i have to run the loop
>   (ng-repeat) no of times based on a parameter set.
>       For Example:-

```
 $scope.rating = 3;
```

> then run the loop (using ng-repeat) for 3 times.

Comment: ng-repeat works with the item collection.. can you please provide the same.. we can put the condition like ng-if=$index<$scope.val to restrict the iteration.

Comment: @NimeshKumar The situation is like, based on a integer value I hve to generate html input tag

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824853/way-to-ng-repeat-defined-number-of-times-instead-of-repeating-over-array

Comment: got it.. solution already there @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824853/way-to-ng-repeat-defined-number-of-times-instead-of-repeating-over-array

Comment: answer to this question is available @
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824853/way-to-ng-repeat-defined-number-of-times-instead-of-repeating-over-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below will the code in your controller..

```
$scope.rating = 3;
$scope.getRating = function(rate) {
    return new Array(rate);   
}
```

Below will be your template.

```
  <div ng-repeat="i in getRating(rating) track by $index">
    <input type="text" name="txt" value="{{$index}}"/>
 </div>
```

Comment: Sorry!! Not working.
Based on a integer value I have to generate input fields. IF a = 5 then generate 5 input fields.

Comment: i am setting your integer value to $scope.rating and it is generating 3 textboxes.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is **cleaner and shorter way**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
 
    app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

      $scope.counter = 2; 
      $scope.generateFields = function(count) {
       return new Array(count);   
      }
     

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
   
  Insert Number To Generate Fields:
  <input type='number' ng-model='counter'/>
  <hr>
  <div ng-repeat="i in generateFields(counter) track by $index">
    <input type="text" name="txt" value="Input Field {{$index}}"/>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not what I want. 
Based on a integer value I have to generate input fields. IF a = 5 then generate 5 input fields.

Comment: just see the updated anser and run code now, its dynamically generating input fields with input given

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by nested ng-repeat using like this :

**In controller**

```
var rating = [3];
//u can set it dynamically too {var rating = [req.body.rating]}
//erq.body.rating is getting value from text/input box
$scope.rating = rating;
```

**In HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat = i in rating>
  <div ng-repeat = ____></div>  // this ng-repeat will run based on rating value
</div>
```