# How to create array of predefined length and then add items to it in Angularjs

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

[Following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824853/way-to-ng-repeat-defined-number-of-times-instead-of-repeating-over-array) this link I am able to display number of available slot in my app but what i need is to add items to these slots on click event to the array.
Untill now I assigned the function value to an array

```
{{heightunit=getNumber(myNumber)}}
```

and then pushing element to that array but if i log the array in console, it did add item to array but in view it doesn't changes its lenght

```
{{heightunit.length}}
```

and array still display empty list

Here is some code

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,item) in getNumber(myNumber) track by $index"   class="wrapper " >
<span class="left">{{myNumber-$index}}Unit</span>
<div id="{{myNumber-$index}}Unit" class="image"  ng-show="item.length">
<img src="{{item.image}}">
</div><span class="drop-right">
<span  ng:click="removeItem(key,item.entity_id)">x</span>
</span></div>
```

in controller

```
$scope.myNumber = <?php echo $instalableunits ?>;
$scope.getNumber = function(num) {
    return new Array(num);   
}
```

Now i created another array

```
$scope.heightunit= [];
```

in view assigned getNumber() value to it

```
{{heightunit=getNumber(myNumber)}}
```

and pushing value to it and logging in console, console shows data in it but it is not getting updated in view

```
$scope.heightunit.push($scope.addproduct[id]);

    console.log($scope.heightunit);
```

Comment: Please provide some code snippet. Your question is not very clear

Comment: @AdityaSingh updated my question with code, thnx

Comment: Why do you have `<?php echo $instalableunits ?>;` in javascript? Does it even return a number value?

Comment: @AdityaSingh, yes it does return the number of slots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps,

**view**

```
{{numbers.length}}
<div ng-repeat="num in numbers"></div>
```

**controller**

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope,$timeout) {
   $scope.numbers = [];
   $timeout(function(){
      $scope.numbers =[1,2]
   },2000);
});
```

Comment: Venu pls check the updated question. numbers should be dynamic, i cannot put static values in it

Comment: Yes Haris, That is the reason I'm changing the number array after 2000 ms timeout so that it will simulate the dynamic change in array. Instead of changing the array in timeout, you can get data from API. It works fine

Comment: Yes thanks it did worked for me, I `heightunit` to the numbers array and it worked. can you please explain the timeout.

Comment: $timeout will register the given function to execute after given amount of time.