# Addition of two values in Angular js

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to add two values using Angular js . I have fetched values from database using $http.get($scope.url) and using the values on html page. now I want to add " 1"  in the value. my code is :-
app.js

```
mainApp.controller("displayController", ['$scope', '$http', 'shareDataService', function($scope, $http, shareDataService) {     
        $scope.url = 'incomeBenefit.php';
        $http.get($scope.url)
        .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;                        
            for(X in $scope.names){ 
                var t_age = $scope.names[X]['client_age'];                                                                                      
                var t_premium = $scope.names[X]['premium'];                                                                                                     
            }           
            $scope.t_age = t_age;
            $scope.t_premium = t_premium;   
        });
}]);
```

and my html page :-

```
        <ul id="form-bt-main" class="sec-row" ng-repeat="n in [] | range:31">
            <li class="form-bt">{{n}}</li>
            <li class="form-bt">{{t_age = t_age +1}}</li>   
        </ul>
```

I want to add '1' in t_age. t_age = '24' and want values like this 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 in li on output screen.

Comment: What about `{{t_age + $index + 1}}`?

Comment: its not working. not adding the values . its giving me 2401 .

Comment: parseInt(t_age, 10) + 1

Comment: {{t_age ++ $index ++ 1}} it will work please test it. One + for concatenation and other for adding two numbers

Comment: it is because t_age is string, parse it: `$scope.t_age = parseInt(t_age);`

Comment: <div ng-controller="ctrl" ng-repeat="number in [1,2,3,4,5]">{{number + 1}}</div> will give you
2
3
4
5
6

Comment: Here is the trick {{age + $index - 1 + 1}}

Comment: @Ranjeetsingh ji i have edited my answer and it's tested try it and if work thums up!!

Answer (score 2):

```
angular.module('app',[]).controller('ctrl',function($scope){
        $scope.age = parseInt('24');
        $scope.names = ["singh","jorawar","kiran"];                
   });
<body ng-controller="ctrl">

<div ng-repeat="name in names">
    {{name}}<br>
    {{age + $index - 1 + 1}}
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<li class="form-bt">{{t_age = t_age +1}}</li>` is **not valid**.

just write `<li class="form-bt">{{t_age +1}}</li>`

or if you want that value in controller as `ng-model`, try this

`<li class="form-bt" ng-model="ages[$index]">{{t_age +1}}</li>`

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.t_age = t_age;` might be a `string`, just use `parseInt(t_age);` A simple fiddle to help..

```
<div ng-app="">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      {{age + 1}}
  </div>
</div>

JS:

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.age = parseInt('24');
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/0wh13nrz/1/

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you have to parse your age which is a string into a `int`

```
parseInt('string', 10);  // parseInt with radix
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
mainApp.controller("displayController", ['$scope', '$http', 'shareDataService', function($scope, $http, shareDataService) {     
        $scope.url = 'incomeBenefit.php';
        $http.get($scope.url)
        .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.data.records;                        
            for(X in $scope.names){ 
                var t_age = parseInt($scope.names[X]['client_age'], 10);                                                                                      
                var t_premium = $scope.names[X]['premium'];                                                                                                     
            }           
            $scope.t_age = t_age;
            $scope.t_premium = t_premium;   
        });
}]);
```

Now you variable `t_age` is an integer

Answer (score 0):

What kind of array is names. If it has **name** object then seeing your controller your html code must look something like this-

```
<ul id="form-bt-main" class="sec-row" ng-repeat="n in names | range:31">
    <li class="form-bt">{{n.name}}</li>
    <li class="form-bt">{{n.client_age = n.client_age + 1}}</li>
    <li class="form-bt">{{n.premium}}</li>
    <li class="form-bt">0</li>
    <li class="form-bt">27000</li>
    <li class="form-bt">0</li>
</ul>
```

and your controllers should not have loop to manipulate the names array, ng-repeat does that looping. Your controller should also change to -

```
mainApp.controller("displayController", ['$scope', '$http', 'shareDataService', function($scope, $http, shareDataService) {     
        $scope.url = 'incomeBenefit.php';
        $http.get($scope.url)
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.names = response.data.records;
        });
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to output values like that, try to ng-repeat number. Example:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="i in getNumber(7)">{{$index+number}}</li>
</ul>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.number = parseInt('24');
$scope.getNumber = function(num) {
    return new Array(num);   
}
```

**live** [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/26511/) **(jsfiddle).**

full post about that trick is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824853/way-to-ng-repeat-defined-number-of-times-instead-of-repeating-over-array)