# ng-repeat fails due to duplicates

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to [ng-repeat something a defined number of times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824853/way-to-ng-repeat-defined-number-of-times-instead-of-repeating-over-array#16824944):

Here's the (reduced) HTML:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="r in getNumber(size) track by $rowIndex">
    <span class="slot" data-y-coord="{{$rowIndex}}"></span>
</div>
```

And here's the JS:

```
$scope.size = 48;
$scope.getNumber = (number) => {
      var arr = [];
      for(var i=0; i<number; i++) {
        arr.push(i);
      }
      return arr;
};
```

I get the error

```
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: r in getNumber(size) track by $rowIndex, Duplicate key: undefined, Duplicate value: 1
```

which I think is weird because I am using 'track by'.

Comment: $rowIndex is undefined. Change $rowIndex to $index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this,change `$rowIndex` to `$index`

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="r in getNumber(size) track by $index">
    <span class="slot" data-y-coord="{{$index}}"></span>
</div>
```

AngularJS does not allow duplicates in a ng-repeat directive. [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes)

Comment: You should highlight the changes, i.e. you changed $rowIndex to $index.

Comment: @nagyf tks for your valuable feedback