# how to use ng-repeat loop by number of count in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to bind html table row by specific count times using angularJS binding like below:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in 5">
       <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If anybody have solution, please reply as possible.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Way to ng-repeat defined number of times instead of repeating over array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824853/way-to-ng-repeat-defined-number-of-times-instead-of-repeating-over-array)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use constructor like this (no code in js required) :

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="n in [].constructor(10)  track by $index">
        <td>abc</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nice to know this .

Comment: Thanks "Gaurav Srivastava", Your answer very useful to me and also will helpful to our angular user colleagues.

Answer (score 4):

Pass the number to a function and generate the array according to it.

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);
app.controller('ctrl',function($scope){
     $scope.getNumber = function(num) {
        return new Array(num);   
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
      <table>
       <tr ng-repeat="x in getNumber(5) track by $index">
        <td>abc</td>
       </tr>
      </table>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can it possible without making an array ?

Comment: any other way without ng-repeat like `for` loop an so on?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will work for you:

Number of visible Values: `{{(data|filter:query).length}}`

Total number of Values: `{{data.length}}`
summary

`{{data.length}}` - prints total number of Values

`{{(data|filter:query).length}}` - prints filtered number of Values

Answer (score 0):

**Sol 1**

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in [1,2,3,4,5]">
       <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Sol 2**

or create blank array in back end and use here like in laravel

```
$scope.newarr = new Array(5);
```

IN angular

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in newarr track by $index">
       <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```