# Iterate through a range of dates in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, date, datetime

I would like to iterate through a range of calender dates, each iteration is +1 day. I would use something built around JodaTime in Java - is there something similar in NodeJS?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You can use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) in a node.js application.

```
npm install moment
```

Then you can very easily do this:

```
var moment = require('moment');

var a = moment('2013-01-01');
var b = moment('2013-06-01');

// If you want an exclusive end date (half-open interval)
for (var m = moment(a); m.isBefore(b); m.add(1, 'days')) {
  console.log(m.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
}

// If you want an inclusive end date (fully-closed interval)
for (var m = moment(a); m.diff(b, 'days') <= 0; m.add(1, 'days')) {
  console.log(m.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
}
```

Hmmm... this looks a lot like the code you already wrote in your own answer.  Moment.js is a more popular library has tons of features, but I wonder which one performs better?  Perhaps you can test and let us know. :)

But neither of these do as much as JodaTime.  For that, you need a library that implements the TZDB in JavaScript.  I list [some of those here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/634824).

Also, watch out for [problems with JavaScript dates](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/06/07/javascript-date-type-is-horribly-broken/) in general.  This affects NodeJS as well.

Comment: I second moment over date-utils

Comment: in moment 2.10 m.add(1,'days') as increment part of for loop.

Comment: Great answer! Keep in mind than in new `moment` version it is recommended to use `m.add(1, 'days')` (replace arguments)

`Deprecation warning: moment().add(period, number) is deprecated. Please use moment().add(number, period).`

Comment: @MateuszRzepa - Updated.  Thanks.

Comment: `var m = moment(a);` might be better here. Cloning 'a' will leave the original date object intact.

Comment: I encountered this problem wherein the last day of the range isn't included I solved it using this `m.diff(b, 'days') <= 0` instead of `m.isBefore(b)`

Comment: I hit a problem here while trying the option with m.diff : When your end date has a time attached (in my case it was 3 p.m.) your loop will end with 1 more day, as the last m.diff is not a full day ...  So careful while converting your date to moment!

Comment: If you want to include the last day, you can use `m.isSameOrBefore(b)`

Comment: m.isSameOrBefore also exists

Answer (score 33):

I would propose a change to the earlier response by Matt. His code will cause a mutation on the `a` object. try this...

```
var moment = require('moment');
var a = moment('2013-01-01');
var b = moment('2013-06-01');

for (var m = moment(a); m.isBefore(b); m.add(1, 'days')) {
    console.log(m.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
}
```

Comment: `var a = moment('2013-01-01');` so `a` is already a `moment`, no need for `var m = moment(a)`. Should be: `for (var m = a; m.isBefore(b); m.add(1, 'days'))`. Also, I think I would prefer `while` loop over the suggested `for` loop.

Comment: @oyalhi `var m = a` would still have the effect of mutating `a` because they both refer to the same moment object. By doing `var m = moment(a)` it generates a new moment object and assigns that to `m`, which is mutated and `a` remains unchanged.

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking. Thank you for the clarification @Guy.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution without external libraries:

```js
  var start = new Date('October 1, 2020 03:00:00Z');
  var now = new Date();

  for (var d = start; d < now; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {
    console.log(d);
  }
```

Result:

```
2020-10-01T03:00:00.000Z
2020-10-02T03:00:00.000Z
2020-10-03T03:00:00.000Z
2020-10-04T03:00:00.000Z
2020-10-05T03:00:00.000Z
2020-10-06T03:00:00.000Z
```

The `Z` at the end of the first date is for UTC. If you want your time zone, just remove the `Z`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the https://github.com/JerrySievert/node-date-utils framework, then you can iterate easily like this:

```
require('date-utils');

var d = new Date('2013-01-01');
var e = new Date('2013-06-01');

for(var i = d; i.isBefore(e); i.addDays(1)) {
  console.log(i.toFormat("YYYY-MM-DD"));  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using momentjs with lodash range:

```
let a = moment('2021-01-01');
let b = moment('2021-01-10');
_.range(b.diff(a, "d")).forEach((d) =>
  console.log(moment(a).add(d, "d").format("YYYY/MM/DD"))
);
```

If you don't want to use lodash, you can get a range like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10050831/751002)

```
[...Array(b.diff(a, "d")).keys()].forEach((d) =>
  console.log(moment(a).add(d, "d").format("YYYY/MM/DD"))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way using moment and while loop.
If you want an exclusive end date

```
let startDate = moment()
let endDate = moment().add(5, 'days')
while (endDate.isAfter(startDate)) {
    console.log(startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
    //increment by one day
   startDate = startDate.add(1, 'day')
}
```

If you want an inclusive end date

```
let startDate = moment()
let endDate = moment().add(5, 'days')
while (endDate.isSameOrAfter(startDate)) {
    console.log(startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
    //increment by one day
    startDate = startDate.add(1, 'day')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A functional approach using [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/) and [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/):

```js
R = require('ramda')
D = require('date-fns')

start = new Date('2013-01-01')
end = new Date('2013-06-01')

numDays = D.differenceInDays(end, start)
R.times(n => D.addDays(start, n), numDays)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it without `moment`.

```js
for (const date = new Date(2022, 10, 1); date < new Date(2022, 11, 1); date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)) {
  console.log(date)
}
```

or even make it as iterate function

```js
export function addDate(date: Date, value = 1) {
  const newDate = new Date(date)
  newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + value)
  return newDate
}

export function* iterateDate(startDate: Date, endDate: Date) {
  for (let date = startDate; date <= endDate; date = addDate(date))
    yield date
}
```

so that you can iterate like this

```js
for (const date of iterateDate(new Date('2022-10-01'), new Date()))
  console.log(date)
```

Answer (score -1):

As much as there are many utilities for this, they might be cumbersome to integrate into a useful loop to check against data.

This should do the trick. It might be overkill, but you could very easily make this more argument based.

```
var moment = require('moment');
var _ = require('lodash');

function(collectionsWithDateValues){
  var slots = [];
  var hours = {
    start: 7,   // 7am
    end: 21,    // 9pm
    window: 2   // How long each item should be slotted for.
  };
  var rightNow  = moment().add(0, 'days').hours(hours.start).minute(0).second(0);
  var cutoff    = moment(rightNow).add(14,'days'); // Check the next 2 weeks.
  for( rightNow ; rightNow.isBefore(cutoff) ; rightNow.add(hours.window, 'hours') ){
    // Check if we're going beyond the daily cutoff, go to the next day
    if(rightNow.isAfter(moment(rightNow).hour(hours.end))){
      rightNow.add(1, 'days').hour(hours.start);
    }
    var foundClash = false;
    _.forEach(collectionsWithDateValues,  function(item){
      // Check if the item is within now and the slotted time 
      foundClash = moment(item.date).isBetween(rightNow, moment(rightNow).add(hours.window, 'hours').subtract(1, 'minutes').seconds(59));
    });

    if(!foundClash){
      slots.push(rightNow.toString());
    }
  }
  return slots;
}
```