# List of dates beween two dates where weekdays are given

Tags: javascript, node.js

> I have a start date [dates are in y-m-d format] (2018-12-23) and an
>   end date(2018-12-31). I want those dates only between the start and
>   end date where the day is Monday,Thursday,Saturday. How can I achieve
>   this using javascript only ?

I have done it in PHP, but I need this in node js.

my PHP code sample is:-

```
<?php
$startDate = '2018-12-23';
$endDate = '2018-12-31';
for ($i = strtotime($startDate); $i <= strtotime($endDate); $i = strtotime('+1 day', $i)) {
  if (date('N', $i) == 1 || date('N', $i) == 2)
    echo date('l Y-m-d', $i);
}
?>
```

Comment: Dates shown aren't in `y-m-d` format as you state. Please provide a [mcve] and show what you have tried

Comment: I have modified the code @charlietfl

Comment: this might be of help to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17163809/iterate-through-a-range-of-dates-in-nodejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you looking for something like this?

```
let getDatesByDay = (start_date, end_date) => {
    let datesArray = [];
    const date1_date = new Date(start_date);
    const date2_date = new Date(end_date);
    let current_date = date1_date;
    while (current_date <= date2_date) {
        if(filterDateByDay(current_date)){
            datesArray.push(`${current_date.getFullYear()}-${current_date.getMonth()+1}-${current_date.getDate()}`)
        }
        current_date = new Date(current_date.setDate(current_date.getDate()+1));
    }
    console.log(datesArray);
}

let filterDateByDay = (date) => {
    const currentDay = date.getDay();
    const acceptableDays = [1,4,6]
    if(acceptableDays.indexOf(currentDay) != -1)
        return date;
    return null;
} 

getDatesByDay("2018-11-01","2018-12-31");
```