# How to count the element present in-between that starting and ending value?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I need some logic from your side.I want to count the number of element present 
n-between that starting and ending value
Like

```
Input :Starting point in 1
          end point is :10

Search :2

count :1(only 2)

Input :Starting point in 1
          end point is :20

Search :2

count :3(only 2, 12 ,20)
function(var start,var end,var searchItem){
for(var start;start<=end;start++)

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895478/does-javascript-have-a-range-equivalent

Comment: no..i think you not understand my question

Comment: Am I understood your question correctly.?

Comment: So please improve your question with consistent example

Comment: Downvoted until you improve your question and show us what you've got so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
function search(start, end, searchItem) {

    var xCnt = 0;

    for (var start = 0; start <= end; start++) {

        if ((start + '').indexOf(searchItem + '') >= 0) {
            xCnt += 1;
        }

    }
    return xCnt;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MKaN9/1/)

Comment: correct but can you explain this logic?if((start+'').indexOf(searchItem+'') >=0)

Comment: @user944513 For example x.indexOf(y) will return the index of y in any substrings of x. If it do not find anything, it will return -1. For More reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: @user944513 Ok so now explain why is this question is tagged with jQuery and Java when obviously is none of them?

Comment: @user944513 you should have tagged this with javascript obviously. And i don't think you want extra comma

Comment: @user944513 logic will be the same, search for index of character in string. But wait, aren't you confusing javascript with java?