# How to arange list of numbers in javascript?

Tags: python, arrays, javascript

In Python:

```
 data = range(50,60,2)
 print data
 [50, 52, 54, 56, 58]
```

How can I do it in js? Looking for simple and shorter way.

```
var range = (start, end) => [...Array(end - start + 1)].map((_, i) => start + i);

var result = range(50, 60, 2);
print(result);
```

Comment: I don't know python but could you explain what your current code is doing?

Comment: It is producing a list between the start and end numbers and with the step given.

Comment: @www139 When 3 numbers: 50, 60, and 2 are given, I have to make a list of numbers between 50 and 60 with step of 2.

Comment: Somebody asked a similar questions knowing the answer for PHP. Some of the answers may help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3895478/1498309

Comment: @I read that link, but could not make answer for my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your own range function:

```
var range = function(start, stop, step){
      step = step || 1;
      var arr = [];
      for (var i=start;i<stop;i+=step){
         arr.push(i);
      }
      return arr;
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I got the following error: Variable must be declared with "var": i

Comment: updated to fix error. This is probably 1) easier to read, and 2) more efficient than using map.