# zipping array of data in js

Tags: javascript, python

```
in python:
data = [50, 52, 54, 56, 58]
answer = list(zip(data[0:],data[1:]))
print answer
[(50, 52), (52, 54), (54, 56), (56, 58)]
```

How can I obtain the same answer in JS?

```
var data = [50, 52, 54, 56, 58];
var answer = ??
print (answer);
```

Comment: why you complicate the python stuff, just `list(zip(data[0:],data[1:]))` will do the job.

Comment: @AvinashRaj i have edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`map`'s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) `callback` argument three arguments.  The element from the array, the *index* of the element in the array, and the array itself:

```
data.slice(1).map(function(el, index) {
  return [data[index], el];
});
```

Comment: thanks. i got [[null,52],[50,54],[52,56],[54,58]]

Comment: @just - yep, off by one error.  We want the indexes to be the same, since we shifted the mapping array by one.  Updated my answer.

Comment: thanks worked, upvoted and accepted

Comment: btw, do u have answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28658522/aranging-floats-in-js