# Polymer: How to repeat dropdown items

Tags: polymer, paper-elements

I am using Polymer paper-dropdown-menu.

I need to show drop down for numbers 1 to 5. The crude way to do it is

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Numbers" >
  <paper-dropdown class="dropdown">
    <core-menu class="menu">
        <paper-item>1</paper-item>
        <paper-item>2</paper-item>
        <paper-item>3</paper-item>
        <paper-item>4</paper-item>
        <paper-item>5</paper-item>
    </core-menu>
</paper-dropdown>
```

Is there a way to avoid repeating `<paper-item>` code by using `<template>`
Something like:

```
   <template repeat="{{ i in [0:25] }}">
       <paper-item>i</paper-item>
   </template>
```

Comment: that is the general idea. i am not sure about {{ i in [0:25] }} but everything else looks good.

Comment: yes, i am sure the syntax will not be {{ i in [0:25] }}. That is more Pythonish. But I do not know the exact syntax to get this done

Comment: Sorry I don't have time at this moment to leave a actual answer. But the demo for paper-drop down-menu has what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do a "range" function to produce the array then use the array in the method already posted.

that would look something like

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Numbers" >
  <paper-dropdown class="dropdown">
    <core-menu class="menu">
      <template repeat="{{range}}">
        <paper-item>{{}}</paper-item>
      </template>
    </core-menu>
  </paper-dropdown>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

then in js you create the range function

```
var range = function(begin, end) {
  if (typeof end === "undefined") {
    end = begin; begin = 0;
  }
  var result = [], modifier = end > begin ? 1 : -1;
  for ( var i = 0; i <= Math.abs(end - begin); i++ ) {
    result.push(begin + i * modifier);
  }
  return result;
}
```

this range function came from this post which also has several diff methods for doing this. [Does JavaScript have a method like "range()" to generate an array based on supplied bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895478/does-javascript-have-a-method-like-range-to-generate-an-array-based-on-suppl)

then you assign the range to the polymer variable the repeat template is using

```
this.range = range(1,25);
```

hope this helps. sorry i couldn't answer yesterday was leaving for work when i sent last response.

edit: a example on plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/4TkQdR2B5vakbwOSAulK?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. This works. I wish Polymer had an inbuilt support to repeat through range of numbers in template instead of support for just arrays. Till then, this will do the work for us

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments there is an example in the demo provided by polymer.
https://github.com/Polymer/paper-dropdown/blob/master/demo.html

```
<x-trigger icon="menu">
  <paper-dropdown class="with-margin">
    with margin<br>
    <br>
    <template repeat="{{countries}}">
      {{name}}<br>
    </template>
  </paper-dropdown>
</x-trigger>


scope.countries = [
  {name: 'Afghanistan', code: 'AF'},
  {name: 'Åland Islands', code: 'AX'}
];
```

Comment: But this needs countries to be an array. To do this I will have to create an array with items as [1, 2, 3, 4, ... 25]. Is there a way to directly tell template how many times to repeat instead of looping on array items