# A method that takes 2 integer values and returns an array. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to know if it is possible to make a method that takes two integer values as parameters and returns them and all the numbers between then in an array.

So for example if my method is

```
function getNumberRange(first, last)
```

And i call it

```
getNumberRanger(10, 13)
```

Is there a way for me to have the answer returned as the following array value

```
[10, 11, 12, 13]
```

Thanks in advance and sorry if this is badly worded.

Comment: Just use for-loop. Very simple.

Comment: this question already done
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895478/does-javascript-have-a-method-like-range-to-generate-an-array-based-on-suppl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course it is.

```
function getNumberRange(first, last) {
   var arr = [];
   for (var i = first; i <= last; i++) {
       arr.push(i);
   }
  return arr;
}
```

You may even want to add a check to make sure first is indeed last than greatest though to avoid errors. Maybe something like this:

```
if (first > last) {
    throw new Error("first must be less than last");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Similar answer that handles sorting high and low

```
function makeArray(n1, n2) {
  var high = n1;
  var low = n2;
  if (n1 < n2) {
    high = n2;
    low = n1;
  }
  var myArray = [];
  for(var i=0; i < (high - low) + 1; i++) {
    myArray.push(low + i);
  }
  return myArray;
```