# Set a range of numbers as a variable (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, variables, range, intervals

Let's say I want a variable to contain numbers from 1 to 100.
I could do it like this:

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,...,98,99,100]
```

But it would take a bunch of time to write all those numbers down. 
Is there any way to set a range to that variable? Something like:

```
var numbers = [from 1, to 100]
```

This might sound like a really nooby question but haven't been able to figure it out myself. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not possible in Javascript.

Comment: @Filipe Really? I can think of many different ways to do it.

Comment: [Yea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895478/does-javascript-have-a-method-like-range-to-generate-an-array-based-on-suppl), there is workarounds, but you can't do natively like in [PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.range.php)

Comment: Does it have to be an array?  The only thing that I can think of similar to this would be an object `{from: 0, to: 100}`.  That fits in a variable, but it is a constructed object that you would have to use by convention.  JavaScript primitives can't really do this.

Comment: Check this [implementation](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/3699e39631cfaa99ca88dc279decb6ff57989413/underscore.js#L691)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10050831/2006429), here are some ways to do it:

`for` loop:

```
var numbers = []
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    numbers.push(i)
}
```

[`Array.prototype.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) + [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var numbers = Array(100).fill().map(function(v, i) { return i + 1; })
```

Or, if you are allowed to use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
var numbers = Array(100).fill().map((v, i) => i + 1)
```

Or, if you are allowed to use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator):

```
var numbers = [...Array(100)].map((v, i) => i + 1)
```

However, note that using the `for` loop is the [fastest](http://jsperf.com/range5254535/2).

Comment: shame IE doesn't support fill. enjoying getting used to dropping all the IE8 restrictions to do cool things like this.

Comment: You're trying to map using the index, but index is second param of map. Add v as value placeholder as first arg - current implementation with map returns an array of 100 NaNs

Comment: I would recommend using `for` loop in this case, it's much faster: http://jsperf.com/range5254535

Comment: @dewd You can use [the polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#Polyfill).

Answer (score 6):

Store the minimum and maximum range in an object:

```
var a = {
    from: 0,
    to: 100
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Supported in all modern browsers including IE9+.

```
var numbers = Array.apply(null,Array(100)).map(function(e,i){return i+1;});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create your own, and store only the limits:

```js
function Range(begin, end) {
  this.low = begin;
  this.hi = end;
  this.has = function(n) {
     return this.low <= n <= this.hi;
  }
}

// code example
var range = new Range(1,100);
var num = 5;

if (range.has(num)) {
  alert("Number in range");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, @MaxZoom had answer that worked for my situation.  However, I did need to modify the return statement to evaluate with && comparison.  Otherwise appeared to return true for any number.

```js
function Range(begin, end) {
  this.low = begin;
  this.hi = end;
  this.has = function(n) {
      //return this.low <= n <= this.hi;
      return ( n >= this.low && n <= this.hi );
  };
}

// code example
var alertRange = new Range(0,100);
var warnRange = new Range(101, 200);

var num = 1000;

if (alertRange.has(num)) {
    alert("Number in ALERT range");
    //Add Alert Class
}
else if (warnRange.has(num)) {
    alert("Number in WARN range");
    //Add Warn Class
}
else{
    alert("Number in GOOD range")
    //Default Class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Python

```
# There can be two ways to generate a range in python
# 1) 
a = [*range(5)]
print(a) 
#[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

# 2) 
a = [*range(5,10)]
print(a) 
#[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Javascript

```js
// Similar pattern in Javascript can be achieved by
let a;
// 1)
a = [...Array(5).keys()]
console.log(a) //[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

// 2) 
a = [...Array(5).keys()].map(value => value + 5);
console.log(a) //[5,6,7,8,9]
```