# Does JavaScript have a method that returns an array of numbers based on start, stop and desired number of return values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looking for something similar to [numpy.linspace](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) to generate an array of numbers based on a starting value, an ending value and the desired number of values in the array.

Example:

```
start=2.0, end=3.0, num=5
result = [2.0,  2.25,  2.5 ,  2.75,  3.0]
```

I've come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895478/does-javascript-have-a-method-like-range-to-generate-an-array-based-on-suppl), but it separates the range based on the steps between.

Does JavaScript have a built-in method to accomplish this?

Comment: Not built-in, no. You could write your own without too much hassle.

Comment: lodash has one: https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.6#range

Comment: @njzk2 not *quite* what OP asked, though ...

Comment: @MatteoTassinari the answer to the OP's question is "no". That's a bit short. Lodash may help anyway. Ramda has a `range` function too, but for integers only, so that would require a `map` on top of the range. (to get the exact thing, you'd need `var step = (end - start) / num;
_.range(start, end + step, step);`)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As others mentioned, there isn’t any built-in function in JavaScript, but here's one way you can implement it yourself. This specific example is a bit verbose so you can see exactly what's going on.

```js
function makeArr(startValue, stopValue, cardinality) {
  var arr = [];
  var step = (stopValue - startValue) / (cardinality - 1);
  for (var i = 0; i < cardinality; i++) {
    arr.push(startValue + (step * i));
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(makeArr(2, 3, 5));
console.log(makeArr(5, 10, 5));
console.log(makeArr(5, 10, 6));
console.log(makeArr(5, 31, 4));
```

If you want the numbers to be rounded to two decimal places, you can change the `arr.push(...)` line to the following:

`arr.push(parseFloat((currValue + (step * i)).toFixed(2)));`

Or

`arr.push(Math.round((currValue + (step * i)) * 100) / 100);`

Comment: Instead of temporarily converting the values to strings, you could also use `Math.round(val * 100) / 100` for rounding.

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah, I thought about that after the fact, but didn't put it in because I had already edited a couple times. Since you mentioned it, though, I will add it as another option

Comment: @mhodges Thanks, I'm fairly new to javascript so this will help me out.

Answer (score 12):

You can make use of `Array.from` instead of manually pushing to the array:

```js
function linspace(start, stop, num, endpoint = true) {
    const div = endpoint ? (num - 1) : num;
    const step = (stop - start) / div;
    return Array.from({length: num}, (_, i) => start + step * i);
}
```

Note that this won't work for num=1 and endpoint=true.