# Gauge Chart in Plotly to give more than 180 degree / more than a circle

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am currently working on a gauge chart as they also feature in the [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/gauge-charts/).

However, everything I can see there is featuring a chart that is half of a circle (180°). I would need something like 300° for the "circle". Is there a way of changing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gauge chart doesn't support showing an angle greater than 180˚

However, you can create a circular gauge chart manually by drawing in each of the components, such as the bar itself, and then the surrounding tickmarks. I'll use a similar approach to a question I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70260645/how-show-a-circular-progress-chart-with-plotly-javascript).

Here is a function that allows you to construct such a chart by specifying the start and ending degrees, the annotation text, and the tickmarks that you want to have in place. I hardcoded the tickmarks in the function because I don't really know how you want to control the tickmarks, but this part of the function can be modified as needed.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import sin, cos, pi
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def degree_to_radian(degrees):
    return degrees*pi/180

def draw_circular_gauge(degree_start, degree_end, annotation_text, r=1.0, padding=0.2, tick_length=0.02):
    radian_start, radian_end =  degree_to_radian(degree_start), degree_to_radian(degree_end)
    theta = np.linspace(radian_start,radian_end,5000)
    x = r * cos(theta)
    y = r * sin(theta)
    fig = go.Figure()

    # draw the bar
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=x, y=y, mode='markers', marker_symbol='circle', marker_size=15, hoverinfo='skip'
    ))
    
    # draw the outer border
    for r_outer in [r-padding,r+padding]:
        fig.add_shape(type="circle",
            xref="x", yref="y",
            x0=-r_outer, y0=-r_outer, x1=r_outer, y1=r_outer,
            line_color="black",
        )

    tick_theta = np.linspace(pi,-pi,13)
    tick_labels = np.linspace(0,330,12)
    tick_start_x, tick_end_x = (r+padding)*cos(tick_theta), (r+padding+tick_length)*cos(tick_theta)
    tick_start_y, tick_end_y = (r+padding)*sin(tick_theta), (r+padding+tick_length)*sin(tick_theta)
    tick_label_x, tick_label_y = (r+padding+0.04+tick_length)*cos(tick_theta), (r+padding+0.04+tick_length)*sin(tick_theta)

    # add ticks
    for i in range(len(tick_theta)):
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
            x=[tick_start_x[i], tick_end_x[i]],
            y=[tick_start_y[i], tick_end_y[i]],
            mode='text+lines',
            marker=dict(color="black"),
            hoverinfo='skip'
        ))
    
    # add ticklabels
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=tick_label_x,
        y=tick_label_y,
        text=tick_labels,
        mode='text',
        hoverinfo='skip'
    ))

    ## add text in the center of the plot
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=[0], y=[0],
        mode="text",
        text=[annotation_text],
        textfont=dict(size=30),
        textposition="middle center",
        hoverinfo='skip'
    ))

    ## get rid of axes, ticks, background
    fig.update_layout(
        showlegend=False,
        xaxis_range=[-1.5,1.5], yaxis_range=[-1.5,1.5], 
        xaxis_visible=False, xaxis_showticklabels=False, 
        yaxis_visible=False, yaxis_showticklabels=False, 
        template="plotly_white",
        width=800, height=800
    )
    return fig  

fig = draw_circular_gauge(180,-120,"300")
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot! I am looking forward to the update and also thank you for the link.

Comment: @JoGa I've updated my answer - hopefully this is helpful!

Comment: @DerekO Very nicely done!

Comment: @vestland thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've been reading the docs and testing by myself, but unfortunately the answer is "no, there isn't a way of showing anything above 180°"