# for loop only returns the initial index in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop

I'm a React JS newbie, so as my practice, I'm creating a dynamic birtdate form. My first challenge is listing of years from 1900 to current year (2017) in a selection of birth year, so I used the `for` loop to make it shorter rather than the horrible way of listing the years one-by-one in the markup. The code below didn't execute successfully, it returned 2017 only.

```
export default class Items extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <form>
          <select name='year' className='yearSelect'>
            <option value="">Year</option>
            {
              for(let yearCount = 2017; yearCount >= 1900; yearCount--)
                return <option value={yearCount}>{yearCount}</option>
            }
          </select>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In the console, it threw an error that says:
[image]

It's the curly brace that bothers me because of the scope so I had to delete the curly brace of the `for` loop and indent the line inside it.

Comment: for loops can't "return" stuff. You will need to run that code before the render (putting it into a variable which you then call in that bracket area)

Comment: looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876978/loop-inside-react-jsx combine it with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895478/does-javascript-have-a-method-like-range-to-generate-an-array-based-on-suppl

Comment: @A.Lau Thanks for the tip. I didn't realize that

Answer (score 1):

Update your code like below.

```
export default class Items extends Component {
  render() {
       let options = [];
         for(let yearCount = 2017; yearCount >= 1900; yearCount--)
             options.push((<option value={yearCount} key={yearCount}>{yearCount}</option>));
    return(
      <div>
        <form>
          <select name='year' className='yearSelect'>
            <option value="">Year</option>
            { options }
          </select>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, bud :)

Comment: just one question... What is that `key` attribute in the `<option>` tag? What does it do?

Comment: while rendering element with looping. you must assign key attribute and it should be unique. based on this key react will manipulate elements here.

Comment: is that attribute always necessary when manipulating DOM elements with loops?

Comment: Yes, you must add key attribute in loops.

Comment: Okay. Thanks again :)