# Is there a JS function that acts like IntStream in Java?

Tags: javascript, stream

In Java8, we can get a stream of numbers in a range like:

```
IntStream.range(1, 3).forEach(System.out::println);
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 3).forEach(System.out::println);
```

How can I get a array in JS like `[1, 2, 3]` with minimum of coding?

The question comes out when I'm solving this: [LeetCode 412. Fizz Buzz](https://leetcode.com/problems/fizz-buzz/#/description)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895478

Comment: @fdsa THX! I searched existing problems with word 'Java' but find no problems...