# Get range of week days based on given date

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Get range of week dates based on given date

```
currentDate = moment().date();
// 19
```

Is it possible to get range of week days in an array, like so?

```
[16,17,18,19,20,21,22]
```

Is there is a short hand method or a known library I could use to achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: All of the functions exposed by moment are [documented on their website](http://momentjs.com/docs/). Asking for a library is specifically off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know relevant library, but there is a way:

```
var currentDate = new Date; // get current date
var first = currentDate.getDate() - currentDate.getDay(); // First day
var last = first + 6; // last day
var list = [];
for (var i = first; i <= last; i++) {
    list.push(i);
}
list
> [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]
```

Comment: got `Uncaught ReferenceError: curr is not defined at line 2` : - /

Answer (score 2):

Here's something you can do:

```
function getWeekDaysByWeekNumber(num) {
    var week = moment().week(num);
    var weekDays = [];

    for(var idx=0; idx< 7; idx++) {
        weekDays.push(week.day(idx).date());
    }

    return weekDays;
}
```

I just tried it, and it seems to work fine.

Explanation:

- `week(num)` method returns a moment object pointing to given week number. For instance `week(20)` would give me a date in 20th Week.
- `week.day(num)` gives me given day (0-6) in the week, where 0 returns the Sunday and 6 returns the Saturday.

Comment: I kept on getting `Uncaught TypeError: week.day is not a function`

Comment: It works perfectly for me. Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4t63xrm5/

Answer (score 0):

Underscore.js has a `range()` function. Is that what you want?
http://underscorejs.org/#range

You could do something like:

```
var RANGE_DISTANCE = 3;
var CENTER = 19;
_.range(CENTER - RANGE_DISTANCE, CENTER + RANGE_DISTANCE + 1)
```

Which you could abstract out to a function:

```
function generateRangeAroundCenter(var center, var range_distance) {
    return _.range(center-range_distance, center+range_distance+1);
}
```

Seems like overkill to import underscore just for that though.

I see some good examples of what you want here:
[Does JavaScript have a method like "range()" to generate an array based on supplied bounds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895478/does-javascript-have-a-method-like-range-to-generate-an-array-based-on-suppl)

There are examples that don't use libraries at all, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19506234/). Let me know if that helps you out, or if you're looking for something else.

Answer (score 0):

The format used for the day ordering
`["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]`

Can get the current weekday to the corresponding locale weekday using `moment().day()`. If today is Wednesday it will return 3.

Depending on these values you can calculate the rest of the days of week.