# javascript - build a string of incrementing numbers

Tags: javascript

I'd like to create a function that I give a number to and it builds me a string of incrementing numbers. I know I can easily accomplish this with a for loop, but is there a cleaner way? Perhaps done in one line (even if it only accomplished the first 2 examples)? Any help is appreciated.

Example:

```
myFunc(3)
output: $1,$2,$3

myFunc(1)
output: $1

myFunc(0)
output:
```

Comment: `I know I can easily accomplish this with a for loop` - doesn't look like you do, because you haven't put any code in your question :p - `const myFunc = n => Array.from({length:n}).map((_, i) => '$' + (i+1)).join();`

Comment: A for loop can be one line of code. I don't think you can get much cleaner than one line...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895478/does-javascript-have-a-method-like-range-to-generate-an-array-based-on-suppl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the array constructor, fill it with `Array.fill` and map back the incrementing numbers, like this

```js
function inc(n) {
  return Array(n).fill(0).map((x,i)=>('$'+(i+1)))
}

console.log( inc(4) )
```

If you want a string, add `.join(',')` at the end

Comment: ```function inc(n) {return Array(n).fill(0).map((x, i)=>('$'+(i+1))).join(',')}
console.log( inc(4) )```

this works

Answer (score 1):

```
var d = function(a) {
    return ((a === 1) ? ("1") : (d(a - 1) + '' + a));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com) question

```js
f=n=>n<1?'':n>1?f(n-1)+',$'+n:'$1'

console.log(f(3))
console.log(f(1))
console.log(f(0))
```